# Overfull hbox - How do I fix this?

Tags: hyphenation

I have a line in tex which has a markup (as a part of a line) as follows:

```
\texttt{org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory}
```

This is giving a overfull `\hbox` warning. How do I fix this?

I am using MiKTeX 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Special case of [boxes - What does "overfull hbox" mean? (Why is there a black mark at the end of a line?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean-why-is-there-a-black-mark-at-the-end-of-a-line?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Overfull `\hbox` warnings are associated with text chunks that overflow over some text boundary. This could be the right text block margin, or some other fixed-width box that contains something that is wider than the width of the box.

In your case, most likely the typewriter-style string `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory` does not match any existing line-breaking rules (since it is technically not a word that has a hyphenation pattern).

You could force hyphenation, if this is what you're after, by inserting `\-` wherever hyphenation could occur. For example:

```
\texttt{org.spring\-frame\-work.beans.fac\-tory.Bean\-Fac\-tory}
```

For more on hyphenations, see [Why do hyphenated words cause margin violations (and how can I prevent it)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34721/why-do-hyphenated-words-cause-margin-violations-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Of course, if hyphenation is not what you're after, you could also issue a `\linebreak` or `\newline` wherever you want to break the line. However, such hard-coded breaks should be left as a last resort since edits to your document may result in improper line breaks if the text is shifted.

Comment: oh how I wish there was an easy way of doing that sort of hyphenation without adding the actual hyphen. Adding hyphens to URLs and such is asking for misunderstandings...

Comment: By default, TeX will *never* hyphenate what's in typewriter type.

Comment: That is a URL? Say what? No `http://`, including some CamelCase? It's anyone's guess.

Comment: @Werner: Well, chimanrao's string definitely is not an URL, but most likely a Java namespace (following the convention to start with a component-wise reversed FQDN). Note that jonalv wasn't the one who asked the original question, and that he wrote "URLs *and such*" (where "such" obviously refers to other cases where an extra hyphen would change the meaning). What he is probably looking for is `""` from babel (however it is only defined for some languages, I think)

Comment: yes this is java code, ideally i would want a line break to be inserted automatically, since this is regular text. I have tried the \- option, it works the problem is that it kind of hinders the reading of the tex file!

Comment: answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299/how-to-get-long-texttt-sections-to-break

Answer (score 18):

I would not hyphenate such terms but break them without hyphenation. One suggestion would be to use package [url](http://ctan.org/pkg/url):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% for demontration only!
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
Line width violation by tt-terms like
\url{org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory} and others.
\end{document}
```

But this would not break inside a letter sequence. You may define (and use) a new url style to change this:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\def\url@allbreakstyle{%
  \def\UrlBreaks{\do\.\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
    \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#%
    \do A\do B\do C\do D\do E\do F\do G\do H\do I\do J\do K\do L\do M%
    \do N\do O\do P\do Q\do R\do S\do T\do U\do V\do W\do X\do Y\do Z%
    \do a\do b\do c\do d\do e\do f\do g\do h\do i\do j\do k\do l\do m%
    \do n\do o\do p\do q\do r\do s\do t\do u\do v\do w\do x\do y\do z%
    \do 0\do 1\do 2\do 3\do 4\do 5\do 6\do 7\do 8\do 9%
  }%
}
\def\url@restrictedbreakstyle{%
  \def\UrlBreaks{\do\.\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
    \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Problem using the default style
Line width violation by tt-terms like this one:
\url{org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory} and others.

% Break inside letter sequences using new style
\urlstyle{allbreak}%
Line width violation by tt-terms like this one:
\url{org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory} and others.

\end{document}
```

You may switch back to the more restricted break style using `\urlstyle{restrictedbreak}`.

Note: If you are using package `hyperref` you need to use the original definition of `\url` without links. `hyperref` provides `\nolinkurl` to do so. But without `\hyperref` this wouldn't be defined. So a general solution, that may be used either with `url` or with `hyperref` would be to define `\nolinkurl` on you own, if and only if it hasn't been defined already:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
% Only one of the following two lines is needed:
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\providecommand*{\nolinkurl}{\url}

\begin{document}
Line width violation by tt-terms like
\breaktext{org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory} and others.

\end{document}
```

You may combine this with defining a new url style shown before.

Note: You should not define `\nobreakurl` reading the argument already, because this would change behavior of several characters at the argument. This is because original `\nobreakurl` and `\url` change cat-code of several characters before reading the argument! So you can write, e.g., `\nobreakurl{this%and%that}` without replacing `%` by a macro like `\%`. But, if you'd define `\providecommand*{\nobreakurl}[1]{\url{#1}}` (using `url` package) this will not work any longer, so don't do it!

Note: You may add additional changes to the new defined url style, e.g., redefinition of `\UrlFont` so change the font, that will be used. Have a look at the documentation of the package for more information about.

Comment: Would `\href{#1}{\protect\nolinkurl{#2}}`, where `#1` is the url and `#2` is something like `org.\allowbreak springframework.\allowbreak beans.\allowbreak factory.\allowbreak BeanFactory` not be sufficient?

Comment: @Stephen: This would not allow breaks everywhere and would set links. The question was how to break text not how to set links. And reading the argument already before calling `\nolinkurl` would prevent `\nolinkurl` to change cat-codes before reading the argument. So it's not a good idea. if you have e.g. `_` at the argument. Maybe `\nobreakurl` or `\Url` could be used instead of `\breaktext`. I've not tested this.

Comment: This works as in the line break happens automatically, however this is not a URL, so I dont want it to show like a url, its like a code snippet, so I was using a different font. How can I prevent it from showing up as a URL?

Comment: @chimanrao: See my additional note about `\UrlFont` and please read the manual of package [url](http://ctan.org/pkg/url). Nevertheless: You've used `\texttt` at your answer and the default `\UrlFont` is `\ttfamily`. So it's the same font. But you may additional use `\urlstyle{tt}` or `\urlstyle{rm}` or `\urlstyle{sf}`. All these url styles are defined by default.

Answer (score 1):

Hyphenation of a fully-qualified Java class name is going to be wrong. While, e.g., `org.spring-framework.beans.factory.BeanFactory` is not valid Java, the rules about hyphens in package names are one of those things that can slip past junior developers consulting printed documentation (and perhaps a few senior devs as well). Better to allow breaks at the periods.

Since no one has mentioned it, I would suggest using `\allowbreak` to allow breaking after the periods. I'd even go one step further and wrap up the `\allowbreak` in its own command to make it a bit easier to type:

*In preamble*:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\0}{}{\allowbreak}
```

*In document*:

```
\texttt{org.\0springframework.\0beans.\0factory.\0BeanFactory}
```

If we're really clever, we could even automate this by creating a new command that splits its argument at the periods, then reassembles it with `\allowbreak` between each piece. I'm not at a computer with LaTeX at the moment, but something like this should work:

*In Preamble*

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\javaname}{ m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { . } { #1 } % ❶
    \texttt{
      \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { .\allowbreak } % ❷
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

*In document*

```
\javaname{org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory}
```

The basic idea here is to split on the periods ❶ then join the split tokens again with a period followed by `\allowbreak` ❷.