# Overfull hbox in a custom section title

Tags: sectioning

I use custom section headings, which for long titles occasionally create an overfull \hbox. Explicit hyphenation does not help. Per this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36767/overfull-hbox-how-do-i-fix-this) I insert `\\` to break the section title, but then the first line is not justified and what is worse, the corresponding TOC entry also includes the line break. Is there a better way to address this issue?

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\define@key{mosquito}{subtitle}{\def\mosquito@subtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\sectionsubtitlefont{\normalfont\huge}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-5pt plus 5pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  { \rmfamily \scshape}{}{0em}{{%
  % subtitle
  \ifx\mosquito@subtitle\@empty\else
{\sectionsubtitlefont\mosquito@subtitle}
\vskip\medskipamount
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt
\vskip\medskipamount
\nointerlineskip
  \fi
  % title
  {\HUGE\bfseries{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
  \ifx\mosquito@subtitle\@empty
    \vskip\medskipamount
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt  
\vskip\medskipamount
\nointerlineskip
\else
\vspace{0.15in}
  \fi
}%
  }
\newcommand{\Section}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{mosquito}{subtitle={},#1}%
  \section}
\makeatother

\setsecnumdepth{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{0.4in}

\Section{This is a very long title, whose string overflows (v1)}
\lipsum[4]

\vspace{0.2in}
\Section[subtitle={This is a subtitle}]{This is a very long title, whose string overflows (v2)}
\lipsum[4]

\vspace{0.2in}
\Section{This is a very long title, whose\\ string overflows (v3)}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `\raggedright` to the definition of `\sectionsubtitlefont`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything. Perhaps I didn't do it right?
`\newcommand\sectionsubtitlefont{\normalfont\huge\raggedright}`

Comment: For anyone else finding this, if it is a one off, using ` \\ ` to break the heading and the optional first argument of the `\section` command to provide the toc entry worked for me as a quick fix, i.e. `\Section[This is a very long title, whose string overflows (v3)]{This is a very long title, whose\\ string overflows (v3)}`. It's not pretty, but if it's just the odd place it may be ok.

Answer (score 2):

You are using contradictory formatting like `scshape` and   `\MakeTextUppercase`. You either use one of them.  Further, as commented by egreg and Gonzalo Medina, you can use `\raggedright` just after `\scshape`:

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\rmfamily\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{%
  % subtitle
  \ifx\mosquito@subtitle\@empty\else
{\sectionsubtitlefont\mosquito@subtitle}
\vskip\medskipamount
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt
\vskip\medskipamount
\nointerlineskip
  \fi
  % title
  {\HUGE\sloppy\bfseries #1}      %%% No \MakeTextUppercase
  \ifx\mosquito@subtitle\@empty
    \vskip\medskipamount
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt
\vskip\medskipamount
\nointerlineskip
\else
\vspace{0.15in}
  \fi
}%
```

If you want them to be upper case add `\MakeTextUppercase` in the place of `scshape`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\define@key{mosquito}{subtitle}{\def\mosquito@subtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\sectionsubtitlefont{\normalfont\huge}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-5pt plus 5pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\rmfamily\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{%
  % subtitle
  \ifx\mosquito@subtitle\@empty\else
{\sectionsubtitlefont\mosquito@subtitle}
\vskip\medskipamount
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt
\vskip\medskipamount
\nointerlineskip
  \fi
  % title
  {\HUGE\sloppy\bfseries #1}
  \ifx\mosquito@subtitle\@empty
    \vskip\medskipamount
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt
\vskip\medskipamount
\nointerlineskip
\else
\vspace{0.15in}
  \fi
}%
\newcommand{\Section}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{mosquito}{subtitle={},#1}%
  \section}%
\makeatother

\setsecnumdepth{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{0.4in}

\Section{This is a very long title, whose string overflows (v1)}
\lipsum[4]

\vspace{0.2in}
\Section[subtitle={This is a subtitle}]{This is a very long title, whose string overflows (v2)}
\lipsum[4]

\vspace{0.2in}
\Section{This is a very long title, whose\\ string overflows (v3)}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem; change the margins to `40mm` (instead of `20mm`) and you'll see the problem reappear. The best thing to do is to add `\raggedright` as in `\titleformat{\section}
  {\rmfamily\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{...}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Your solution is the best one!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks. I knew that won't solve the problem. But egreg has laready commented about `\raggedright` above. Hence I thought, he will give an answer. Not to be intrusive :). Now that you caught me, I will add it to the answer. Hope that it will be OK.