# what dose this means Overfull \hbox?

Tags: warnings

I would like to know what is this means?

Overfull \hbox (0.97128pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 30.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is a warning informing you that something in line 30 is wider than the textwidth and sticks into the margin by 0.9pt. To spot the line in your resulting pdf more easily, add the `draft` option to your documentclass. The corrensponding line in the pdf will now be highlighted with a black rectangle at the right margin.

Comment: Related: [What does “overfull hbox” mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/134144)  and [Overfull hbox - How do I fix this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36767/134144)

Comment: Thanks for your replay cgnieder. How  should I add  the draft option in my document ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "overfull hbox" mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean)

Comment: I recommend looking at this: https://img.devrant.com/devrant/rant/r_206855_UPJi3.jpg