# Lines that doesn't fit the structure (overfull hbox)

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

In some places in my doucemnt I am experiencing this \hbox full error, which results in words sticking out on the right side of the marginal. I have inserted the code below.

I realize now when I try this code block on [LatexBase](https://latexbase.com/d/bc5735be-276d-4318-8392-fe69c59886e2), that it looks just fine, the lines seem to get longer there even though I use the same geometry code.

I think this is because I an not using the `\documentclass{article}` but this template https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis. Maybe this makes in hard to help with, but I am throwing it out there anyway, hopefully I can get some tips.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}


\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    headheight=4ex,
    includehead,
    includefoot
}

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=4.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
}

    
\begin{document}

Traditionally in Econometrics, statistical models such as 
Auto-Regressive (AR) and Generalized Autoregressive 
Conditional Heteroskedasticity (GARCH) models have been 
used to estimate forecasts of time series.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is probably the same as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36767/overfull-hbox-how-do-i-fix-this), because LaTeX does not know how to hyphenate "Heteroskedasticity" nor "GARCH" (nor I...). Try `Hetero\-skeda\-stici\-ty` (and use the correct hyphenation, I'm just guessing here --- never learnt how to hyphenate english, I just trust LaTeX).

Comment: @Rmano - Good try! Speaking for myself, I'd go with `\hyphenation{het-ero-ske-das-tic-ity}`. (Aside: I'm an econometrician, so I'm quite familiar with the word...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have something more like

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}


\begin{document}

Traditionally in Econometrics, statistical models such as Auto-Regressive
(AR) and Generalized Autoregressive Conditional Heteroskedasticity (GARCH)
models have been used to estimate forecasts of time series.


\end{document}
```

which is 12pt overfull (marked with the rule due to `draft` option)

[image]

In general you could add more technical words to TeX's hyphenation, but you can't really hyphenate GARCH.

You could add `sloppy` to avoid overfull boxes by stretching space:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{sloppypar}
Traditionally in Econometrics, statistical models such as Auto-Regressive
(AR) and Generalized Autoregressive Conditional Heteroskedasticity (GARCH)
 models have been used to estimate forecasts of time series.
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But TeX warns

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 3954) in paragraph at lines 7--8
```

and this is not clearly better.

You could use microtype (which often saves the day)

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

Traditionally in Econometrics, statistical models such as Auto-Regressive
(AR) and Generalized Autoregressive Conditional Heteroskedasticity (GARCH)
models have been used to estimate forecasts of time series.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is 2pt overfull you might decide to accept that which doesn't look too bad if you remove the `draft` rule.

Failing that you could re-word a bit or when you have really finished all edits micro-manage the space eg

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

Traditionally in Econometrics, statistical models such as Auto-Regressive
(AR)\hspace{-.3pt} and Generalized Autoregressive Conditional Heteroskedasticity
\!(GARCH) models have been used to estimate forecasts of time series.

\end{document}
```

no warnings:

[image]