# Do I have to care about bad boxes?

Tags: boxes, warnings

When I compile my PDF from LaTeX source, do I have to care about all the messages (currently 28) about 'bad boxes'?

The PDF seems fine to me.

Comment: Genearlly: Yes, you have to. It really depends on what boxes are these.

Comment: It's going to depend mainly on how large the "bad" boxes are. Are you using the `microtype` package and its protrusion feature? If so, getting messages about overfull boxes (of width usually no larger than 1 or 2 pt) is quite normal.

Comment: If you are _expecting_ 2pt overfull, then you can set `\hfuzz=2pt` and tex will then warn you if it is more than that.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean

Comment: i don't see it mentioned elsewhere, but when using the `picture` environment, an overfull box message will result if the width specification for the picture is larger than the text width -- *even if the content of the `picture` is well within the text width*.  no end of headaches.  be careful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

It is worth noting that TeX doesn't make the value judgements here.

The *user*, or more likely, the class file on behalf of the user, has *set* constraints on the amount by which boxes may overflow, the amount of stretching allowed on short pages etc. TeX only warns if these user-set constraints are exceeded.

So if you are setting difficult material with lots of big unbreakable chunks, that means that the constraints are probably wrong. (They were designed mostly for copy that is mostly text that can be hyphenated and with enough interword stretch to get tight fitting boxes.)

Rather than TeX trying to meet un-achievable constraints and then complaining about failing to meet them, it is better to modify (relax) the constraints. But before doing that you should make sure that they really are un-achievable and it is not just user error preventing tex from finding a good layout.

*Some general notes added as requested:*

**Settings that *only* affect warning messages.**

There are several setting that only affect the messages that TeX sends
out. For example if you know that some boxes will be overfull by 2pt
(and you don't mind this) but you want to be warned for a box that is
1cm too full then set

```
\hfuzz=2pt
```

this will make *no* difference to the typesetting, but will suppress
warnings for boxes that are only slightly overfull.

```
\vfuzz
```

is the same thing for vertical boxes.

Similar are `\hbadness` and `vbadness` which are a measure of how
*bad* a box is, typically how much white space has had to be stretched.
the exact number is not usually that relevant but 0 is good and 10000
is infinitely bad (TeX's badness calculation arbitrarily forces any
very bad boxes to this amount).

The parameter `\tolerance` is what tells Tex how much stretching
should be allowed. TeX tries to line-break a paragraph in such a way
as to keep the badness below the specified tolerance.

Good typographic quality would indicate that you shouldn't ignore (or
turn off) these warnings, However sometimes it makes sense. The PDF
version of the MathML recommendation for example is set automatically
by LaTeX from sources primarily designed for the normative HTML
version. Because it has many one or two line paragraphs and many
indented tables and examples, the right hand margin is very uneven
anyway and so allowing the occasional overlarge example to protrude
isn't so bad, it is set with

```
\hfuzz=20pt
\vfuzz=20pt
\hbadness=2000
\vbadness=\maxdimen
```

**Settings that don't affect the typesetting of good boxes**

TeX3 introduced a parameter `\emergencystretch` which allows extra
stretch to be more uniformly added to a paragraph if the default
stretching does not produce a good break. Setting this to a non zero
value can sometimes help.

**Settings that do affect the typesetting.**

LaTeX has a command `\sloppy` that sets up looser typesetting

```
\def\sloppy{%
  \tolerance 9999%
  \emergencystretch 3em%
  \hfuzz .5\p@
  \vfuzz\hfuzz}
```

The setting of tolerance makes it rather more sloppy than is perhaps
desirable, and it is probably worth experimenting with just setting
`\emergencystretch`.

The default fussy settings used by LaTeX are

```
\def\fussy{%
  \emergencystretch\z@
  \tolerance 200%
  \hfuzz .1\p@
  \vfuzz\hfuzz}
```

For vertical page breaking, if you are getting underful boxes in the
output routine you may prefer `\raggedbottom` rather than
`\flushbottom` as this adds stretchable space at the end of each page
so no page will be underful (but short pages will be silently
accepted). It is possible of course to have something between these
two extremes, that adds glue that only extends a finite amount rather
than fill glue.

The above are the main *global* settings however every aspect of the
document design affects this. In particular, if the space between
display elements such as lists and displayed maths, and the space
between paragraphs, is *stretchy* then it it is much easier for TeX fo
find a "good" page break, however this means that there is no vertical
alignment between lines on different pages. especially for book designs
using two page spreads, designers often aim to keep text on a grid
where text always aligns on fixed positions. This usually means that
you have to make all the vertical spaces much more rigid, which
increases the chance of Tex giving warnings about over or under-full
vboxes.

Comment: What do you do when you can't figure out which thing is causing the badness? I sometimes get repeated warnings which all give some hard-to-decipher line number such as 0 and it often isn't at all clear what is meant to be bad. (Especially in `beamer`.)

Comment: @cfr `\showoutput` can help, otherwise hard to say anything, post a question wth an example?

Answer (score 62):

Yes, you should definitely take care of them.

1. `Overfull \hbox` messages tell you that some line sticks out over the right margin;
2. `Underfull \hbox` messages tell you that some line is poorly typeset (or that you've improperly used `\\` to leave a vertical space (for example, typing two `\\` in a row);
3. `Underfull \vbox` messages usually tell you that a page is poorly typeset.

How much badness *requires* action is difficult to say, but I would *never* accept a final PDF where there's some `Overfull \hbox`.

Comment: You were faster than me, I would just add that 3. happens mostly with section titles being moved to the top of the next page, or when you use `[H]` (here and only here) `table` or `figure`, which are large in height; the same applies for inline `tabular`, `\includegraphics`, ...

Comment: exactly what is bad to a section title being moved to the next page? Isn't that expected behaviour?

Comment: @romeovs The problem is that the page is "too short" -- In that case, LaTeX tries to increase the vertical spaces between paragraph etc. to make the page go to the very bottom. It does not look good when a page is shorter, because it looks like the page is the last in the chapter.

Comment: I actually never understood why Overfull hboxes are permitted at all. Surely I can understand "a lot of whitespace" as being a reasonable warning, but "sticking out of the margin" should definitely be an error in my opinion.

Comment: @UncleZeiv It's not difficult to avoid overfull hboxes, but doing so one must be prepared to accept horrendously spaced lines. Taking care of a few lines is not so burdensome, particularly when we know that the other lines are correctly typeset.

Comment: but what can be done about Overfull \hbox?

Comment: @alfC Some small text editing usually solves the problem. I use to say that very rarely the first or even the fourth version of a text has so polished a prose that it's become untouchable. :)

Comment: small text editing means changing the choice of words? (just asking).

Comment: @alfC That's one of the possibilities. In some case just altering the word order can help; adding or removing a "that"; applying a hyphenation that TeX wouldn't have chosen; …

Comment: thanks, I think also that the worst cases happen in scientific writing when there are inline long equations in two-column format. In that cases one can for example consider making the equations not-inline.

Comment: @alfC Long equations are a sure source of headaches; overlong ones should almost always be considered for a display.

Comment: Is it possible to throw an error (rather than a warning for overfull hboxes)? I am editing a very large document, with a narrow margin and the draft black rectangles aren't always helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: @KarthikRaman No, it's not possible to change internal TeX warnings into errors without changing the program.