# How to automate vfill on last paragraph before a page break in case of underfull vbox

Tags: vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\flushbottom vs \raggedbottom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65355/flushbottom-vs-raggedbottom)

I have my Thesis with nearly 200 pages. I have encountered many underfull vbox problems due to the high of equation-to-text ratio. LaTeX likes to space out paragraphs in underful vbox scenarios, leading to some paragraphs being awkwardly at the bottom, see the screenshot attached.

[image: The need of vfill]

By affixing `/vfill` at the end of that paragraph, I can move the awkward stretch to the bottom of the page, which is much less noticeable to the eye.

How does one normally deal with this, such as something like flush top? Is there a way to automate adding `/vfill` to the every last paragraph before page breaks or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65355/323. Short answer, use `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: @Aditya thanks, seems to work well. I tried searching for the answer and couldn't find it before.