# paragraph indentation strange

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, paragraphs

I have a first line of a second paragraph (from \section title) that is not behave like other first line in other paragraph. I need it to be indented but it din't even if I put \hspace{} before it. But when I make a copy of it, I found it normal. Please help. 
These are the screenshoot:
[image: original text]

[image: copy of the original]

Comment: What exactly is the problem (which indentation do you want to change)? And also please post some code so that we can see your documentclass and configurations (MWE).

Comment: the first image, there is an extra line in order to make an indent of the second paragraph. other paragraphs are normal. I don't want the extra line.

Comment: Then we definitely need a MWE showing what you tried and where you failed (= lets us reproduce your issue).

Comment: please always provide code that reproduces the problem, it is very hard just to debug from an image. either you have `\flushbottom` and that is the only way tex can make the last line reach the bottom of the page, or you have a spurious space at the end of the paragraph, hard to tell

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65355/flushbottom-vs-raggedbottom

Comment: the extra space appears to be less than a full baseline in height, so it's most likely because of `\flushbottom`.  see the cited "maybe related" question.

Comment: The problem will be clear only if I post the entire document (9 pages). Besides, I don't have right to share the article. I'm sorry for that. But, @David Carlisle, there is no \flushbottom and \raggedbottom in the article. extra space seems to reduced when I reconstructed paragraph before or after it.

Comment: no you can always create an example and always avoid posting the original text. page breaking only depends on the number of lines in the paragraph so replace a 5 line paragraph by `a\\a\\a\\a\\a` and similarly the rest of the document, you should soon have an example small enough to post while showing the issue.