# Unwanted extra vertical space

Tags: spacing, vspace

Today I encountered this problem after the dictation of some lines with Dragon 13.
The problem is eliminated if I copy and paste the same content on another page, or when I delete part of the things dictated with dragon. so if I rewrite the same things with the keyboard, the problem does not occur.
I do not insert the MWE because it would not make sense. I insert two screenshots

--------------------FIRST--------------------

```
\begin{align}
10\cdot 100= 1\cdot^{3} \;\rightarrow\; R_{e} =\nicefrac{10^{3}}{10^{-5}} = 10^{8}\nonumber
\end{align}
Le dissipazione viscose pertanto, non possono indicare se esiste o meno una condizione di turbolenza nel momento in cui l'aria attraversa la collina. Quest'aspetto invece è fondamentalmente legato alle forze di galleggiamento e quindi al numero di Froude.
Nel caso di \textit{stratificazione stabile}, le forze di galleggiamento smorzano le oscillazioni che subiscono le particelle e il flusso rimane laminare ossia non si genera turbolenza.\\
```

[image]

--------------------SECOND--------------------

```
\begin{align}
10\cdot 100= 1\cdot^{3} \;\rightarrow\; R_{e} =\nicefrac{10^{3}}{10^{-5}} = 10^{8}\nonumber
\end{align}
Le dissipazione viscose pertanto, non possono indicare se esiste o meno una condizione di turbolenza nel momento in cui l'aria attraversa la collina. Quest'aspetto invece è fondamentalmente legato alle forze di galleggiamento e quindi al numero di Froude.
Nel caso di \textit{stratificazione stabile}, le forze di galleggiamento smorzano le oscillazioni che subiscono le particelle e il flusso rimane laminare ossia non si genera turbolenza.\\
La stratificazione è \textit{stabile} quando si hanno densità maggiori in basso e minori in alto ($caldo/freddo$).
In questa condizione pur incontrando un fenomeno perturbativo, non si genera distacco dalla vena, poiché vi è un pacchetto di strati fluidi che in corrispondenza della collina vengono compressi. Il mescolamento pertanto, avverrà subito dopo la stratificazione stabile, cioè superata la collina il flusso si allarga con turbolenza decrescente.\\
```

[image]

---------------UPDATE---SOLUTION----------------

I found the solution. it is not an image, but a too large "note" box, which was influencing the above text. I neglected the detail.

```
bla bla bla

\begin{itemize}
     bla bla bla
\end{itemize}

 bla bla bla

\begin{align}
 bla bla bla
\end{align}

bla bla blaa:

**\newpage**   %<-----------------------
\begin{note}{Riassumendo}
    \begin{itemize}
         bla bla bla
        ..................
    \end{itemize} 
\end{note}
```

[image]

Comment: One would assume you're referring to `SECOND` as being the current problem you're experiencing?

Comment: @Werner yes a frustrating problem. I do not understand if it's a dragon or unimacro problem.

Comment: @Antonio What are in the page containing error? As I know, if on page 10 you have a very big figure, on page 12 you have another huge figure, and on page 11 you have not much text, then the spacing on page 11 is huge.

Comment: @JouleV Thanks for the idea. I found the solution. it is not an image, but a too large "note" box, which was influencing the above text. I neglected the detail

Comment: The extra vertical space is added because LaTeX is trying to make all the pages the same size.    If you don't want this behaviour, then set `\raggedbottom`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65356/15036).

Comment: @Thruston your observation is correct, thank you. Initially I suspected it was a problem with DNS and Vocola (I neglected the details). I thank you for the observation