# How can I typeset the reduced Planck constant (ℏ)?

Tags: symbols

How can I typeset the symbol for the [reduced Planck constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) (from quantum theory)? It consists in an italic "h" whose upper part is crossed by a small "slanted" bar:

[image]

For information, this slanted bar also occurs quite often with the letter "l" (ell) in Polish. Example: the Polish word for "word" is "slowo", where the letter "l" bears a slanted little bar.

Is there a package that provides that symbol?

Second question: please tell me where to look for and how to correct the LaTex PDF warning

```
overfull/underfull \hbox or \vbox
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm "tagging" the question so that it can be found by someone daring Unicode in a web search: the reduced Planck constant aka the Dirac constant is written ħ, pronounced as "h bar".

Comment: To my knownledge, "reduced Planck constant" is the most widely accepted name for the physical constant you're referring to. Feel free to revert my edit if you don't like it. Also, you're asking two unrelated questions, here. Please ask only one question per post. That said, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes) should answer your question about bad boxes.

Answer (score 6):

We answer in the language of codes ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\begin{document}
  $\hbar$ $\hslash$
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\hbar` needs no packages while `\hslash` needs `amssymb`.

Generally we prefer one question per thread. The badboxes are detailed in your `.log` file with line numbers. You may also add `--file-line-error` option to `pdflatex` to get C like error messages. Further, if you add `draft` option to the `\documentclass[draft]{...}`, the `badbox`es will be shown as black box in the pdf file. Good luck with it.