# Is there any automatic way to detect hanging text on the right in LaTeX?

Tags: margins, babel, hyphenation, text-manipulation

I wonder if there is any automatic approach to detect hanging text all throughout the 200-page thesis, mostly due to hyphenation issues.
Consider the output below, there is like a subtle hanging text (yellow), which I think would be a very tedious task in a thesis last-minute situation to check and to look for such irksome typesetting flukes. The same issue will pop up each time you do some text edit, and will continue to be bothersome if you seek a perfect right-margin-typesetting text, it is like a moving target.
I wonder where in the log file, one can read hints pointing out to these lines? or may be a package to detect them?

**Example**

[image]

**Update**

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
In summary, IL-17 can be produced by innate and adaptive cells, but more profoundly from innate sentinel cells of the immune system. 
The nTh17 is a novel subset that is thymic-\hspace{0pt}dependent and shows a distinct developmental pathway from iTh17 cells that are derived from naive T cells.

In summary, IL-17 can be produced by innate and adaptive cells, but more profoundly from innate sentinel cells of the immune system. 
The nTh17 is a novel subset that is thymic"-dependent and shows a distinct developmental pathway from iTh17 cells that are derived from naive T cells.
\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

**Question**
What is the shorthand equivalent to writing `thymic-\hspace{0pt}dependent` in LaTeX? or is there any way to set this kind of hyphenation *globally* for all *already hyphenated* words?

Comment: Those are `overfull box`es in the log file.

Comment: unfortunately, not helpful, sometimes misleading or unnoticeable may be, e.g., `Overfull \hbox (0.11844pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2819--2837`, I checked these lines and were very acceptable, is there any threshold no. above which it is worth checking in PDF?, besides, I guess it is impractical, I got many of these `overfull` mesges, but fine with them, some belong to tables, or other floats but not *text*.

Comment: If you think .11pt is acceptable, set \hfuzz=.12pt and then TeX will not tell you about those, and just tell you about unacceptable ones

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850

Comment: by default tex doesn't hyphenate hyphenated words, most babel languages have a shortcut such as `"-` for an explicit hyphen that allows hyphenation or you can use `-\hspace{0pt}dependent` which will also allow hyphenation

Comment: The above was answering a comment that vanished:-)

Comment: that was helpful, the comment is exactly answered by now.

Comment: for me, it like I have to think twice before introducing hyphenated words in text.

Comment: if you think this question is a duplicate, feel free to close.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, pls can you look at the update, you can upgrade your comments to an answer, I am satisfied with `-\hspsace{0pt}depedent` solution, though a little bit verbose, and I couldn't reproduce that using the `"-` or `"=` shorthands in `babel`, where is the problem?

Comment: Heiko's answer probably covers everything now (I don't think shorthands are activated in english option)

Comment: Check out pages 10 and 11 of the [current `babel` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel). Summary: English defines no shorthands (p. 11) and `\defineshorthand[]{}{}` may be used to define your own for a document (p. 10).

Comment: @PaulGessler, I asked a separate question for this thing, can you pls care to answer with code?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179066/how-to-set-a-global-setting-for-hyphenation-of-already-hyphenated-words

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Class option `draft`/`\overfullrule`

The class option `draft` of the standard classes (`article`, `report`, `book`) sets `\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt}`. Then the overfull `\hbox`es are much more easier to find on a page, because they get a black rule, whose width is controlled by `\overfullrule`.

Also some other classes set `\overfullrule` if option `draft` is given, e.g. `memoir`, `KOMA-Script` classes. If another class does not provide such an option or if someone do not want to use a global option `draft`, because it is also seen by the packages, `\overfullrule` can be set manually, see above.

### Ignore small overfull warnings/`\hfuzz`

Settings to `\hfuzz` to ignore small overfull `\hbox` values are already covered in the comments and the cited [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50850/16967).

### Own `babel` shorthands

Package `babel` allows the definition of personal shorthands. Example, modified from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf):

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}[2014/03/24]% v3.9k
\useshorthands*{"}
\defineshorthand{"-}{\babelhyphen{hard}}
...
thymic"-dependent
```

Comment: what about KOMA-script class?

Comment: @doctorate the KOMA classes act the same in this respect

Comment: apart from detection, I am fine with `-\hspace{0pt}`, pls read updated question, any idea?