# Underfull hbox in keywords environment

Tags: ieeetran

New to Latex, I'm using IEEEtran template to writing some paper, but there is warning of `underfull \hbox` in the keyword environment, I googled it but have not found relevant information, can someone help me? Thanks very much!

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url} \usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=on}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx} \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Probabilistic password model,
Probability-threshold graphs,
Probabilistic password model,
Probabilistic password model
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that just means that some white space got stretched beyond the amount that you have specified that white space can stretch. It may be Ok to ignore it or you may want to set the text ragged right rather than justified. Impossible to say as you have not shown any code. It is not an error it is a specific warning about how the words on that line fit on to the length of that line. So any fix has to be specific to the text in your case.

Comment: Do you mean the IEEEkeywords environment?  Since it uses \centering, I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the problem is I have a keyword composed of 3 words: ABCD-EFGH IJKL, the first line of compiled keywords ends with ABCD-, I can resolve the problem by remove - between ABCD and EFGH and add hyphenation of EF-GH, but without removing the - between ABCD and EFGH, the problem cannot be solved

Comment: @JohnKormylo, do you mean it is impossible to solve the problem?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, yes, I mean the IEEEkeywords environment

Comment: it is impossible to tell you what to change if you do not show the code that is causing the problem. Please ensure that any question asking about a warning message includes a small example a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that shows the error. Then people can easily debug it and suggest changes.

Comment: No, John meant it's impossible to get an underfull box warning in the scope of  `\centering`, so there is something that you are not telling us that is causing the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I see, thank you, to reproduce the warning:
`\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=on}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
 Probabilistic password model, Probability-threshold graphs, Probabilistic password model, Probabilistic password model
\end{IEEEkeywords} 
\end{document}
`

Comment: Thanks but better to add into the question (I did it this time) formatting of code in comments isn't that good:-)

Comment: In relation to @JohnKormylo's comment re `\centering` that would have the same effect on spacing as the `\raggedright` I used below, . It _is_ used in the class definition of the keywords environment however it only uses centred setting in single column, and you have double column (although we didn't know that until you posted the example:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example posted produces

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 2318) in paragraph at lines 10--15
[]\OT1/ptm/b/it/9 Index Terms\OT1/ptm/b/n/9 ---Probabilistic pass-word model, P
robability-
```

which means that the white space on that line is over stretched. Actually 2318 isn't that bad. So one reasonable alternative is just to accept it as it is as it is anyway a formal list not a normal paragraph of text that needs to be read as text and where large spaces are distracting.

The alternatives are to tell tex to ignore this amount of badness (the default threshold is 1000 so you could make it 2500

```
\begin{IEEEkeywords}\hbadness=2500
```

and the warning would go (without changing the formatting)

Or you could tell tex to re-arrange the white space, eg set as `\raggedright`

```
\begin{IEEEkeywords}\raggedright
```

also has no warning, but has a different setting, with short and long lines, but regular inter-word space.

See further discussion about hbadness at

[Do I have to care about bad boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850)

Comment: I just find that if I add hyphenation by `\hyphenation{thres-hold}`, and remove `'-'` in `'Probability-threshold graphs'`,  then the problem also resolved, but I cannot use `'-'` in keyword `'Probability-threshold graphs'`, otherwise the trick does not work, even if I add `\hyphenation{th-res-hold}`. it seems it is forced to start newline at '-' in keyword `'Probability-threshold graphs'`.

Comment: tex doesn't automatically hyphenate words with explicit hyphens  you could use `Probability-thres\-hold` in the document which would make tex happier but might break whatever automatic indexing the ieee do with keywords (I don't know) @K.Wanter