# Which LaTeX command prints a warning message about "Overfull \hbox"?

Tags: tex-core, warnings, logging

I want to override the command that prints `Overfull \hbox...`, but it seems that it's not `\GenericWarning`. What is it?

Comment: It is a message from the tex engine.

Comment: I believed that it can't be override

Comment: increase \hfuzz

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50850/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my intent is _not_ to fix the document, but to catch the warnings in the log and turn them into errors, [here](https://github.com/yegor256/fail-fast)

Comment: @yegor256 I'm afraid that's impossible for pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX, that message is absolute low-level. Maybe you can hook into something in LuaLaTeX...

Comment: you can not make that an error from tex, but you can of course arrange your processing pipeline raises an error: grep the log for `underfull hbox` and flag a non zero exit status if found

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434830/how-to-use-silence-package-to-silence-underfull-and-overfull-warnings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from the tex egine and in classical TeX can not be changed.

In luatex there is a callback that allows the warning to be replaced by arbitrary Lua code, so here I use it to raise a tex error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\directlua{
luatexbase.add_to_callback(
"hpack_quality",
function(i,d,h,f,l)
if(i=="overfull") then
tex.error("Overfull line: ".. 
          string.format("\@percentchar.4f",d/65536,3) .. 
          "pt in paragraph lines " ..
           f .. "-" .. l)
end
end,
"error on overfull hbox"
)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One twoxxxxxxxxxxxxxx threexxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxxthree xxxxxxxxxxxx four
One two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx three xxxxxxxxxxxx four

\begin{quote}
  \rule{12cm}{1cm}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Produces three errors:

```
! Overfull line: 5.4100pt in paragraph lines 22-40.
<argument> ...ype:D \tex_hskip:D \c_zero_dim \fi: \tex_par:D 
                                                  \hook_use:n {para/after}\@...

l.40 
   
? 
! Overfull line: 7.9400pt in paragraph lines 22-40.
<argument> ...ype:D \tex_hskip:D \c_zero_dim \fi: \tex_par:D 
                                                  \hook_use:n {para/after}\@...

l.40 
   
? 
! Overfull line: 46.4331pt in paragraph lines 42-43.
<argument> ...ype:D \tex_hskip:D \c_zero_dim \fi: \tex_par:D 
                                                  \hook_use:n {para/after}\@...

l.43 \end{quote}
              
?
```