# I get 'Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph”, how to fix?

Tags: errors

```
\section{Experience}
\begin{twenty} 
    \twentyitem{2018-now}{PhD student, FWO-SB fellowship}{Ghent University}{The research mainly focused on the development of easy-read out nanofiber sensor networks and their implementation in food packaging. The second part of the research concerned the use of organic dyes in  novel polymeric light harvesting systems.}

    \twentyitem{2017-2018}{Research scientist}{VKC-Centexbel, Kortrijk}{The technological research and service centre for the plastics processing industry, is to support companies and organizations by means of research, testing and consultancy. During this period I improved my knowledge on processing and utilizing most of the commonly used polymers in various applications. Upon these polymers I gained field experience in SEM analysis, IR, DSC, TGA and mechanical characterization. As a consultant, I've acquired problem-solving skills to supply company specific solutions for my clients.}

    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850