# Where Should \HBADNESS Be?

Tags: badness

Because there are too many `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active` messages, I am trying to use `\hbadness=10000` to suppress them. If I use TeXworks, then where should I locate `\hbadness=10000`? I tried the following, but it did nothing.

```
\documentclass{book}
\hbadness=10000
\begin{document}
This is the document with many underfull vbox messages.
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: setting `\hbadness=10000`  (or `\vbadness`) means you are telling tex you really do not care how bad the output is. Why use TeX at all in that case? It would be far better to fix the errors in your document that are causing the warnings. However putting it where you show will work. If you have an example where it is not working as expected then edit the question toshow an example of your issue.

Comment: but to suppress _vbox_ errors you need to set `\vbadness` not `\hbadness`

Comment: The problem is that it's not horizontal badness that's to blame, but it's vertical badness, so you would need to set `\vbadness` and not `\hbadness`. That said, you may want to examine what the root cause of the underfull `\vbox` error is rather than just turn off the error.

Comment: My apologies, but I was not me—I didn't think about the difference between H and V there. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `vbox` you would set `\vbadness` not `\hbadness`.

This document produces the warning if you remove the marked line.

```
\documentclass{book}

\vbadness=10000 % don't do this
\begin{document}
aaa

bbb

\pagebreak
ccc
\end{document}
```

However by setting `\hbadness` or `\vbadness` to 10000 you are telling TeX not to warn you even if its internal checks on the quality of the output say that it is *as bad as possible*.  It would be much better to fix the errors that are causing the warnings rather than just silence the warning.

See [Do I have to care about bad boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850)

Comment: Thanks for help. I was combining multiple documents and wanted to check other warnings first before the bad boxes. Of course I wanted to correct all the unexpected underfull messages but after the warnings—there were too many underfull messages related to undirected footnotes, so I couldn't even match them all.