# How do you fix underfull hbox warning?

Tags: warnings, debugging

I am trying to write my thesis proposal paper in Latex. Here's the summarized code since most of it is all about the paper I wrote:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
    \setlength{\parindent}{2.30em}
    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[top=1.8in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.75in, right=1.25in, headheight=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\sloppy
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen

% Fonts
\usepackage{sectsty} 
    \allsectionsfont{\normalsize}

% References
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex} % for APA 7
\addbibresource{References.bib}

%Pagination
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- use fancyplain instead fancy
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Caption
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang, font=normalsize, labelfont=bf, justification=justified, labelsep=period}

% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{./Figure/}}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.png}

% Spacing
\usepackage{setspace} % control linespacing
    \setstretch{1.5}
    
\makeatletter 
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}         % Removes space above \chapter head
    \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}        % Removes space above \chapter* head
    \chapterfont{\normalsize \centering \MakeUppercase}
    \partfont{\normalsize \centering \MakeUppercase}


% Renew commands
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % titles
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % page
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\clearpage

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
    \chapter{Methodology}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
    \label{ch:Methodology}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.45]{4.8_LabelImg_Interface.png}
        \caption{
            LabelImg Interface
        }
        \label{fig:LabelImg Interface}
    \end{figure}

    The second phase involves image pre-processing and augmentation. Roboflow, a developer framework for computer vision procedures, will be used for image pre-processing and annotation. The annotated images will be uploaded to a dataset and Roboflow will apply the pre-processing and augmentation processes to the dataset. Also, Roboflow will apply annotation corrections to ensure that the annotations were correctly made. 

\end{document}
```

Relevant image: 4.8_LabelImg_Interface.png
[image: 4.8_LabelImg_Interface.png]

However, this line has an `Underfull \hbox (badness 1199)` warning:

```
The second phase involves image pre-processing and augmentation. Roboflow, a developer framework for computer vision procedures, will be used for image
```

Output in PDF:
[image: Output]

I tried to use microtype and emergencystretch but they weren't able to remove underfull errors. How do I remove this warning? Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it cannot hyphenate Roboflow. Try `Robo\-flow` on the first line. If you use it often, you can add `\hyphenation{{Robo-flow}` or something similar in your preamble. I hope it helps!

Comment: Oooh I see @mickep. That fixed that problem, thank you! Also, the References also encountered a similar error (I didn't share it in my question). Does this mean that I have to rework references?

Comment: It is not an error, merely a warning. And indeed, if you care for the output, it is good to finally go over these and act.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I tend to mix up errors and warnings haha

Comment: 1199 isn't very bad at all (it's only a fraction over the default point at which latex wouldn't warn. Given that you have `\sloppy \emergencystretch=\maxdimen` you are already telling tex you pretty much don't care how much white space stretches and you will tolerate any amount of stretch, I wouldn't worry about the warning (or just increase `\hbadness` to silence it.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850

Comment: Gotcha, thank you @DavidCarlisle!