Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 25--27
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
% updated with editorial comments 8/9/2021

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Some Common Elements}
\subsection{Sections and Subsections}


\subsection{Citations to the Bibliography}
For multiple citations code as follows: {\tt{$\backslash$cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3\}}}
 which will produce . For reference ranges that are not consecutive code as {\tt{$\backslash$cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref9\}}} which will produce  

\vspace{11pt}

\vfill

\end{document}

Question: why does the above code generate the warning "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 25--27" ?
Every Tex.StackExchange question I found about "Underfull \hbox" is about line breaking, but I did not use \\ nor \newline on lines 25-27. What else could be generating the error? I'm using Overleaf.

Such messages are essentially harmless: badness 2080 is not really so large. Worry about it only when your document is in final form; at that point you can try small changes in wording or decide to leave it as is. What citation style are you using? Is it author-year or numeric?

you haven't provided any code that shows the problem so it is hard to say. It is only a warning, and not that bad, it just means tex could not find a good linebreak. make sure you have the correct language specified. as a common source of problems is trying to hypenate words in other languages using the default US English hypenation rules. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850

@egreg My document is almost final form, but the compile timeout is expiring on the free plan of Overleaf, and I'm trying to fix anything that could possibly slow down the compilation process. Also, 2080 is not the biggest number, it's just the first one.

@BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah You can generally ignore anything under 8000. The warning does not slow things down (you can always add \hbadness=8000 to your preamble so you won’t see most of the warnings. If you don’t see anything objectionable in the output, don’t worry about it.

@DavidCarlisle OK, I changed the example so it surely gives the warning.

After the edit the warning is that the boxes have badness 10000 (which is the maximum badness)

That is telling you that the white space has been over stretched, as you can clearly see in the output. You have monospace \cite  (for some reason set using \tt that has not been defined by default in LaTeX for 30 years, \texttt{.. would be the normal LaTeX syntax).  But as the monospace text will not break over the line it has to go to the next and so the spaces are over-stretched to justify the line.
You have to decide what to do, you could ignore the warning,  you could add manual linebreaks you could restore a normal \parfillskip with the ieeetran setting two-line paragraphs are almost always going to produce underfull boxes
or you can change the wording to make it better fit the space

\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
% updated with editorial comments 8/9/2021
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Some Common Elements}
\subsection{Sections and Subsections}


\subsection{Citations to the Bibliography}

1

For multiple citations code as follows:
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3\}} which will produce . For
reference ranges that are not consecutive code as
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref9\}} which will produce

\bigskip

2

For multiple citations code as follows:
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,\linebreak ref2,ref3\}} which will produce . For
reference ranges that are not consecutive code as
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,\linebreak ref2,ref3,ref9\}} which will produce

\bigskip

3

\begin{sloppypar}
For multiple citations code as follows:
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3\}} which will produce . For
reference ranges that are not consecutive code as
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref9\}} which will produce
\end{sloppypar}


\bigskip

4

For multiple citations, you may code as follows:
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3\}} which will produce . For
reference ranges that are not consecutive code as
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref9\}} which will produce


\bigskip

{\setlength\parfillskip{0pt plus 1fill}

5
  
For multiple citations code as follows:
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3\}} which will produce . For
reference ranges that are not consecutive code as
\texttt{\textbackslash cite\{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref9\}} which will produce

}
\bigskip

\vfill

\end{document}


Apparently, the suggested solution still generates "Underfull \hbox" warnings.

@BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah some do some don't  with a 2 line paragraph with a large unbreakable tt section it might be unavoidable if you really want justification. Consider a paragrapg A B  you have things set so all lines including the last have to be full width so there is no way to avoid over stretching the space other than change the text

@BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah but I suspect your real paragraphs have more than 2 lines

I don't really need to use tt. It's just the easiest example I had at hand. The explanation you provided in your answer is enlightening.
