# Warning message overfull \hbox what does it mean?

Tags: warnings

When I run my latex the document is set, but it takes a long time and I have lots of warnings like this:

> Overfull \hbox (4.0pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active

What does this mean?

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69759/overfull-underfull-hbox-warnings-when-compiling-the-document?