# Best way of breaking a line?

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them)

I'm just trying to break a line at some point, e.g.

```
Word 1\\
Word 2
```

Which will give me an underfull hbox (`badness 10000`) warning on building on line "Word 1". This is not really bothersome since the result is what I want. But since I'm getting a warning, I'm guessing there's a better way to break lines?

Comment: I don't get a warning when I do this. What type of document is it? Are you using pdflatex?

Comment: Why do you want to break this way? There is most of the time a better way, such as a list environment or a normal paragraph break.

Comment: I agree with Juri Robl on this. If you really insist on doing this, I believe inserting `\hfill` before the manual linebreak should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Please *always* post complete documents that show the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


Word 1\\
Word 2

\end{document}
```

produces no underfull box warnings.