# there is no line here to end. \end{frame} in beamer

Tags: beamer, vspace, allowframebreaks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
    \author{Anshul Sharma}
    \title{Forced Oscillator}
    \institute {CENTRAL UNIVERSITY OF HIMACHAL PRADESH}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Contents}
\begin{enumerate}\Huge
    \item  Aim
    \item Objectives
    \item Apparatus
    \item Theory
    \item Experimental Setup
    \item Observations
    \item Results

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Aim}\Large
To understand the motion of the system when being driven by an external force sinusoidally.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]\vspace{10pt}
\frametitle{Objectives}
\begin{enumerate}\huge
    \item To study the Amplitude Resonance curve at variour frequencies.
    \item To determine the quality factor of our given system (i.e.  Spoke).
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]\vspace{10pt}
\frametitle{Apparatus}\huge
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Exp-Eyes
    \item DC motor
    \item Spoke
    \item Meter Scale
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theory}\Large
\textbf{Forced Oscillator}: When a system is subjected to an external force, (say periodic) the oscillator will exhibit Forecd oscillations and is called Forced Oscillator.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Equation of motion for Forced Oscillator}
If a system is given an force to oscillate as long as the driven frequency $\omega$ is given to it, then by Newton 2nd law\\
\begin{equation*}
m\ddot{x}+2m\mu\dot{x}+\k2x=f_0(t)
\end{equation*}
or
\begin{equation*}\ddot{x}+2\mu\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x=\frac{f_0(t)}{m} \end{equation*}
where \textbf{m} is the mass of the system being oscillated.\\
\textbf{$\mu$} is the damping coefficent.\\
\textbf{$\omega_0^2$} is the natural frequency of the system.\\
\textbf{$f_0$} is the external force being applied to the system.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
If the external force being applied is sinusoidal we have,\\
\begin{center}
    f=$f_0\sin\omega t$ \\
\end{center}
     Then our equation of motion becomes,\\
\begin{equation*}\ddot{x}+2\mu\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x=\frac{f_0\sin\omega t}{m} \end{equation*}
\textbf{$\mu$} is the damping coefficent.\\
\textbf{$\omega_0^2$} is the natural frequency of the system.\\
\textbf{$\omega^2$} is the driven frequency supplied to the system.\\
\textbf{$f_0$} is the external force being applied to the system.\\
This is a linear nonhomogenous differential equation.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
The solution of the equation is assumed as,\\
\begin{equation*} x=A\sin(\omega t-\theta). \end{equation*}
where \textbf{A} is the amplitude and \textbf{$\theta$} is the phase angle.\\
On solving the differntial equation we get,\\
\begin{equation*}  A = 
\frac{f_0/m}{\sqrt{(\omega^{2}-\omega_{0}^2)^2+4\mu^{2}\omega^{2}}} \end{equation*} and \\
\begin{equation} \tan{\theta} = 
\frac{2\mu\omega}{(\omega^{2}-\omega_{0}^2)} \end{equation}.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
As resonance occurs at,\\
\begin{center}
$\omega_{r}$ $\sim$ $\omega_{0}$
\end{center}
Therefore resonant frequency become,
\begin{center}
    \begin{equation*} \omega_r = \sqrt{\omega_{0}^2-2\mu^2} \end{equation*}
    \end{center} 
And the amplitude becomes,\\
\begin{equation} A_{max} = \frac{f_0/m}{2\mu\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\mu^2}} 
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Quality Factor}
\textbf{Quality Factor}: It is defined as 2$\pi$ times the ratio of the average energy stored in the system to the energy dissipated per cycle by the applied force.
Where for forced oscillator the quality factor is,\\
\begin{equation} Q=\frac{\omega_{0}}{2\pi} \end{equation}.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Quality Factor}
It can also be calculated by the amplitude resonance curve as,
\begin{equation} |\omega_{h}-\omega_r|=\Delta=\mu\sqrt{3} 
\end{equation}.
This shows that for small $\mu$, $\omega_{h}$ is close to $\omega_r$, 
$\Delta$ is small and the resonance is sharp.\\
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{"C:/Users/vinay kumar/Desktop/latex work/IMG_20180518_111515"}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:img20180518111515}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Experiment Setup}
Experiment Setup Screenshot
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../screenshot001}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:screenshot001}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Calculating Natural Freqeuncy and damping factor}
Calculation of natural frequency and damping factor by Exp-Eyes Screenshot.\\
1) \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{../screenshot002}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:screenshot002}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Calculating Natural Freqeuncy and damping factor}
2) \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../screenshot003}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:screenshot003}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Applying differnet frequency from Exp-Eyes}
Screenshot\\
1) \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../screenshot004}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:screenshot004}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Applying differnet frequency from Exp-Eyes}
Screenshot\\
2) \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{../screenshot005}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:screenshot005}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Observations}
 \textbf{1)Frequency and damping coefficent of oscillator from expeyes} \\ \\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Frequency} &\textbf{Damping Factor} \\
    \hline
    1.56&0.536 \\
    \hline
    1.56&0.476 \\
    \hline
    1.56&0.402 \\
    \hline 
    1.56&0.476 \\
    \hline
    1.56&0.387 \\
    \hline
    1.57&0.410 \\
    \hline
    1.56&0.407 \\
    \hline
    1.56&0.345 \\
    \hline
    1.56&0.391 \\
    \hline
    1.55&0.412 \\
    \hline  
    Mean=1.56$\pm$0.01&0.424$\pm$0.001 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\textbf{2) Variation in frequency from tracker and expeyes}\vspace{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Frequency from expeyes}&\textbf{Frequency from Tracker} \\
    \hline
    1.20&1.22 \\
    \hline
    1.22&1.24 \\
    \hline
    1.28&1.24 \\
    \hline
    1.32&1.32 \\
    \hline
    1.36&1.36\\
    \hline
    1.44&1.46 \\
    \hline
    1.50&1.49 \\
    \hline
    1.51&1.50 \\
    \hline
    1.52&1.56 \\
    \hline
    1.57&1.59\\
    \hline
    1.64&1.62 \\
    \hline
    1.74&1.74\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\textbf{3)Amplitude(calculated from tracker) for various frequencies from waveform generator}\vspace{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Frequency ($\nu$) In Hz}&\textbf{Amplitude (A) in cm} \\
    \hline
    1.22&7.38 \\
    \hline
    1.24&7.61 \\
    \hline
    1.29&9.16 \\
    \hline
    1.32&10.53 \\
    \hline
    1.36&12.00 \\
    \hline
    1.46&15.75 \\
    \hline
    1.49&24.82 \\
    \hline
    1.50&25.89 \\
    \hline
    1.56&23.52 \\
    \hline
    1.59&6.39 \\
    \hline
    1.62&5.53 \\
    \hline
    1.74&4.12 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Results}\huge
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Theoretical natural Frequency of the Spoke=(1.570$\pm$0.004)Hz.
    \item Experimental natural Frequency of the spoke=(1.50$\pm$0.05)Hz.
    \item Theoretical quality factor of the spoke=
    \item Experimental quality factor of spoke=
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Note that in oder to mark the code as code, just take it into the cursor and press the `{}` above the text field when you post or edit. I believe the issue is the double `\\\ \\\` after ` \textbf{1)Frequency and damping coefficent of oscillator from expeyes}`. There are *much* more elegant ways to achieve vertical spacing, if that's the reason why you had it.

Comment: You have 21 frames here.  Could you give us just the frame that causes the error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please inform yourself about MWEs :D

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The problem also occurs for this drastically cut down document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Observations}
  \textbf{1)Frequency and damping coefficent of oscillator from
  expeyes} \\ \\
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It is caused by `\\ \\`.  The `beamer` package redefines `\\` so that it can not be used on a blank line; the first `\\` creates a newline, the next is then on that blank line.

If you need larger space here, either use something like

```
\\[2ex]
```

where the `2ex` gives `2ex` more vertical space, or better

```
\medskip
```

(or `\bigskip`) after a blank line.  Cf. [What does double backslash in LaTeX mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225893/15925)