# Finding the cause for an overfull vbox

Tags: formatting, compiling, warnings

When compiling my document I get the following warning message:

```
Badbox line 1: Overfull \vbox (1.77525pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Now from Google I learned that this warning refers to a formatting problem while Latex is adding headers and footers. Therefore I guess the reference to "line 1" in the warning message does not help me in finding what causes the problem. The first line in my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
```

So my question is this: How can I find what part of my document causes this warning, given the message shown above?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/5764)

Comment: Related: [Do I have to care about bad boxes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50830/5764)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The first thing to do is to look in the actual `.log` file: `Badbox line 1` is not something that would be output by (La)TeX so it must be the result of some filtering by your editor/IDE. By looking at the actual log message and comparing with the information in the two links in Werner's comments, you should be able to track it down.

Comment: You have presumably defined a non-standard header, but not declared enough space for that header to be placed. (If you use fancyhdr package to define the header you usually get a warning about that from the package) but unless you make an example that shows the problem, hard to give specific help

Comment: @PaulGessler: Thanks Paul, your comment has helped me to track down the problem. It seems the fully warning message was hidden by Texmaker, so I didn't know there was more to see at all. I found the full `.log` now and thus also the cause for the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthias thanks for keeping us updated. I voted to close your question as a duplicate of our general question about eliminating bad boxes; that way your question here can help lead future visitors to our main question/answers on bad boxes. Cheers!