# Unused global option(s) [english]

Tags: paragraphs, class-options

Whenever I compile my TeX file, I get the following warning

```
Unused global option(s) [english]
```

and

```
Underfull \hbox(badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 27-28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the class you're using and/or your document preamble, but you're probably calling

```
\documentclass[...,english,...]{<class>}
```

If the (global) option `english` is not used by the `<class>` it is passed to and package you might load along the way. If TeX reaches `\begin{document}` without the `english` option being used, it'll issue a warning and reference all unused options.

Typically `english` is used with [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel), so you can add

```
\usepackage{babel}
```

to your preamble for `english` to be properly used, or remove the `english` option altogether from loading the class.

Your second question is addressed here: [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/5764)

Answer (score 2):

Unused global option(s) [english] probably means you have done something like

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
```

and that the global option `[english]` isn't doing anything.

The underfull \hbox (badness 10000) warning is usually generated by abruptly ending a line of text using `\\`. To end a paragraph, you should use a blank line. There are probably lots of other ways to generate this warning, but without seeing an example code, this is the best guess I can make.

Comment: Thanks the second error is solved. But the first warning still appears. What I use is \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn,english]{iiscthes}

Comment: @user87834 just delete `english` from the line you quote.

Answer (score 0):

NB! Global options can also be case sensitive. Writing "a4paper" (correct) instead of "A4paper" (incorrect) removed the unused global options warning in my case.