# Bad boxes appearance

Tags: pdf

I compile everything correctly. It is shown a document as I wanted it.
 But then, on the bottom of the page, it is written: errors: 0, warnings: 0, bad boxes: 31. What are those Bad Boxes?? That appearance hits my nerve because of a word bad, and I see nothing bad in my document, it compiled correctly, what can be bad?? Are bad boxes something I should worry about?? Is it possible to somehow reduce their number or even to erase them??
 Please, help.

Comment: See if [Do I have to care about bad boxes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50830) and [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138)/ give you any useful hints.

Comment: One more: [What does "overfull hbox" mean?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35)