# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines in table

Tags: tables

I'm new at LaTEX. I'm learning it by myself so this maybe is a beginner problem.
I'm getting the warning:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines
```

In this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|p{5.5cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Name}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{OPt 1}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Opt2}} \\ \hline

 Entorno   & Fibra ADSL (velocidad?) con router ?  &  SIM ?Vodafone? \\ \hline
 Entorno    & Fibra (velocidad?), router ? & SIM ?vodafone? \\ \hline
 Entorno        & Wifi velocidad? & SIM ?vodafone? \\ \hline
 Entorno     & WiFi velocidad? & SIM core ? \\ \hline
 Entorno   & Conexión TCP Wifi. &  Ethernet entre dos ordenadores Toshiba Tecra. \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabla resumen de entornos}
\label{tab:una}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And I don't know what's wrong here, can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156/124577).

Comment: I completed your example to be a document so that people can run it and see the problem but it does _not_ generate the message shown, it warns about the `[]` option `LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.` and that the table is too wide `Overfull \hbox (75.11218pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--20` but no underfull box warning. The warning you show almost always comes from `\\ ` being mis-used at the end of a paragraph but you do not have any use of `\\ ` outside tables in the code you posted.

Comment: unrelated but `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}` should be `\multicolumn{1}{c|}` except in the first column otherwise you get doubled lines, one at the right edge of column 1 and a second at the  left edge of column 2

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I have an `overfull \hbox` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The underfull box problem, as @TeXnician and @DavidCarlisle pointed out, is certainly due to other portions of your code, and probably related to terminating paragraph with `\\` instead of `\par` or an empty line.

---

Regarding the problems that your code *does show,* here are some remarks.

The main problem, as the people in the comments have specified are that:

1. you give an empty `[]` option to table (it's better to leave out the entire optional parameter then)
2. you have a table that is too wide for the page
3. As @DavidCarlisle pointed out `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}` should become `\multicolumn{1}{c|}` to avoid double lines.

---

## Possible solutions

The part 2 problem is the hardest to solve, especially if you really want the table cells to be that wide. I will propose a couple of solutions which can, or can not be acceptable to you.

### Meddling with paper and keeping the separator (not optimal)

The easiest one is just to enlarge the margins and specify some paper size. I did this with `a4paper`, and loading the `geometry` package with `a4paper` option. For this (fairly common in Europe) papersize, it is sufficient to do the job, provided that you compress a bit one of the columns (I chose the last one, by 2mm).

I also loaded `array` and `ragged2e`, in order to define columns that are ragged right, which is good solution for something so confined as your table. I'm providing this solution just as a reference, and I don't think it's good typography

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|P{5.5cm}|P{4cm}|P{3.8cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Name}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{OPt 1}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Opt2}} \\ \hline

 Entorno   & Fibra ADSL (velocidad?) con router ?  &  SIM ?Vodafone? \\ \hline
 Entorno    & Fibra (velocidad?), router ? & SIM ?vodafone? \\ \hline
 Entorno        & Wifi velocidad? & SIM ?vodafone? \\ \hline
 Entorno     & WiFi velocidad? & SIM core ? \\ \hline
 Entorno   & Conexión TCP Wifi. &  Ethernet entre dos ordenadores Toshiba Tecra. \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabla resumen de entornos}
\label{tab:una}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Better typography (reducing also width)

A fair and square solution to your table impagination problem would require many more information and also the understanding of what you need. As a general solution, I think it's safe to proceed using the following steps:

1. remove vertical separators. They're ugly, almost never serve a purpose other than making the table less readable
2. making the first column width automatically calculated
3. using the `booktabs` separators to make a more professional look

So here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lP{4cm}P{4cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Name}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{OPt 1}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Opt2}} \\ 
\midrule

 Entorno   & Fibra ADSL (velocidad?) con router ?  &  SIM ?Vodafone? \\ 
 Entorno    & Fibra (velocidad?), router ? & SIM ?vodafone? \\ 
 Entorno        & Wifi velocidad? & SIM ?vodafone? \\ 
 Entorno     & WiFi velocidad? & SIM core ? \\ 
 Entorno   & Conexión TCP Wifi. &  Ethernet entre dos ordenadores Toshiba Tecra. \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabla resumen de entornos}
\label{tab:una}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And a peek:

[image]