# TeX's expansion rules: a case study with a token-list register

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, token-lists

I'm trying to figure out TeX's rules of expansion. Consider the following plain TeX manuscript:

```
\toks1{hello}%
\toks10{world}%
\def\mac{0}%
\the\toks1\noexpand\mac%
\bye
```

When this manuscript is processed with pdftex, the following pdf results:

[image: Hello, world!]

and the log file contains the following warning:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
[]\tenrm world

\hbox(8.5+0.0)x469.75499
.\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0
.\tenrm w
.\kern-0.27779
.\tenrm o
.\tenrm r
.etc.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] )<./c
mr10.pfb>
```

If I replace both occurrences of `0` in the manuscript by `2`, so that the manuscript becomes

```
\toks1{hello}%
\toks12{world}%
\def\mac{2}%
\the\toks1\noexpand\mac%
\bye
```

the pdf contains a single line:

> hello2

and no warnings in the log file.

Could someone please explain to me why the pdf document looks the way it does, as well as what the warning means, and why it is being reported. Also, please walk me through the steps TeX goes through in processing my manuscript. Thanks.

Comment: warning is about something else. But what is the problem here? toks is expecting a number until it finds something that doesn't expand to a number and that's 1

Comment: @percusse: Sorry, I don't follow your line of thought. Do you mean to say that in the line that starts with `\the`, TeX first processes `\the\toks1` and after it finishes it processes the rest of the manuscript? But if this were the case, the output would have been simply "hello", and not what we see.

Comment: What is confusing you about the output?

Comment: @percusse: Firstly, the fact that both "hello" and "world" are printed. I could kinda wrap my mind around any of the following outputs: 1. "hello", 2. "hello0", 3. "world". Secondly the whitespace: two lines (or is it three?) and the second one is indented.

Comment: @percusse: What is the warming about?

Comment: Explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll skip over the three assignments and go straight to

```
\the\toks1\noexpand\mac
```

The `\the` primitive inserts the content of a register: here a `\toks`. After the `\toks` we need a number, so TeX goes looking for one: it finds a literal `1` then a `\noexpand`, which temporarily turns `\mac` into `\relax` and so terminates the search for a number.  `\toks1` contains `hello` so that gets inserted (and starts a paragraph), then TeX re-reads `\mac` which is now 'back to normal': a macro expanding to `0`. So the paragraph you see is `hello0`. (There is of course a paragraph indent as one would expect at the start of a paragraph.)

So why does `world` get inserted? That happens as you've picked `\toks10`: alter the number and it vanishes. In plain TeX, `\headline`  is `\toks10` so gets inserted as part of the page finalisation: it's got nothing to do with the specific input you have (other than that you've set it!). Of course, this is why we almost always use the allocation system for registers.

Here, `\tracingall` is probably your friend: the example is short and the trace is clear.

Comment: Thanks. You wrote: "alter the number and it vanishes". If I replace both occurrences of `0` in the manuscript by `1`, then the output is: "world". But according to your explanation, it should be: "world1", no?

Comment: Or, rather, "hello1". At any rate, not "world".

Comment: I get as expected hello1 if I replace the 0.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't. Even if I add `\font\myfont=cmtt14\myfont%` as the first line.

Comment: @EvanAad I don't follow: can you edit the question?

Comment: I did as you requested.

Comment: You should better show the actual code instead of describing what you did. Imho the only way to get "world" is to replace the 0 by nothing ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I now listed the actual code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: OK, I restarted my editor and reran, and now I get what you did.

Comment: I restarted my editor and reran, and now I get "hello2", as would be predicted by your explanation. But what about the warning message? Your answer doesn't address it at all.

Comment: @EvanAad In the output routine, there is `\line{\vbox to8.5\p@{}\the\headline}\vss}` and with `\toks10={world}`, which is the same as `\headline{world}`, there is no glue to fill up `\line` (which is `\hbox to\hsize`).