# LaTex ERROR_Overfull \hbox (2.92001pt too wide) in paragrah at line

Tags: sharelatex, cv, awesome-cv

I am currently working on resume using latex, but I am going crazy with this overfull error. 
Can you guys please have a look at the attached file below and help me?? THANKS!!! Below is the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}  
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=1.5cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.1cm, footskip=.5cm}  
\fontdir[fonts/]  

\begin{document}    
\makecvheader[C]

\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {Isaac Kweon~~~·~~~Résumé}
  {\thepage}

\cvsection{Education}

\begin{cventries}

\cventry %line 23  
   {Hebronstar Strategy Consultants}  
    {Intern (Research Assistant)}  
    {Seoul, S.Korea}  
    {May. 2017 - July. 2017}  
    {  
      \begin{cvitems}  
        \item {Researched about domestic start-up M\&A and IPO cases and discussed methods for expanding start-ups that are under investment}  
        \item {Communicated daily with 12 start-ups for weekly checkups and organized mentoring programs and Demo Day}\vspace{2mm}    
      \end{cvitems}
    }

\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't sent external links - they will be dead soon and so your question can't help others. Create a complete minimal example and add it to your question. Btw: overfull messages are warning, not errors - and 2.9 pt is not very much.

Comment: Short answer: they are not errors.

Comment: Because I am using this for my resume, I want to get rid of the warning and fix the 2.9pt too. Sorry I am new to this world, but by minimal example, are you guys referring to the code?

Comment: @IsaacKweon Getting rid of warnings is very good! However, the more you work with LaTeX, the more warnings you get which (nearly) cannot be get rid of. For example, only using my mother tongue language in the document causes two warnings, but as they do no harm, I ignore them.

Comment: I've changed it..please have a look

Comment: @IsaacKweon The code should be compilable *for us*: since we don't have your `\input` files, your code is still useless to us. But alas I don't really think a MWE is required here, if you haven't yet, see [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/117534). And as others have already mentioned, it's a warning, not an error, so it's nothing to lose sleep over if you can't get rid of them.

Comment: and this [What does "overfull hbox" mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/117534)

Comment: Is `awesome-cv.cls` somewhere available for download?

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=32131&p=107747#p107747)

Answer (score 2):

In your case the issue comes from the definition of command `\makecvheader`.  Because you do not use a photo you can simply comment the code for adding a photo to get rid of the warnings:

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\renewcommand*{\makecvheader}[1][C]{%
  \newcommand*{\drawphoto}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{}{%
      \newlength{\photodim}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoshape}{circle}}%
        {\setlength{\photodim}{1.3cm}}%
        {\setlength{\photodim}{1.8cm}}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoedge}{edge}}%
        {\def\@photoborder{darkgray}}%
        {\def\@photoborder{none}}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[\@photoshape, draw=\@photoborder, line width=0.3mm, inner sep=\photodim, fill overzoom image=\@photo] () {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }
  \newlength{\headertextwidth}
  \newlength{\headerphotowidth}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{
    \setlength{\headertextwidth}{\textwidth}
    \setlength{\headerphotowidth}{0cm}
  }{%
    \setlength{\headertextwidth}{0.76\textwidth}
    \setlength{\headerphotowidth}{0.24\textwidth}
  }%
  %\begin{minipage}[c]{\headerphotowidth}%
    %\ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoalign}{left}}{\raggedright\drawphoto}{}
  %\end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\headertextwidth}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{L}}{\raggedright}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{\raggedleft}{\centering}}
    \headerfirstnamestyle{\@firstname}\headerlastnamestyle{{}\acvHeaderNameDelim\@lastname}%
    \\[\acvHeaderAfterNameSkip]%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@position}}{}{\headerpositionstyle{\@position\\[\acvHeaderAfterPositionSkip]}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@address}}{}{\headeraddressstyle{\@address\\[\acvHeaderAfterAddressSkip]}}%
    \headersocialstyle{%
      \newbool{isstart}%
      \setbool{isstart}{true}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \faMobile\acvHeaderIconSep\@mobile%
          \setbool{isstart}{false}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{mailto:\@email}{\faEnvelope\acvHeaderIconSep\@email}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{http://\@homepage}{\faHome\acvHeaderIconSep\@homepage}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@github}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://github.com/\@github}{\faGithubSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@github}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@gitlab}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://gitlab.com/\@gitlab}{\faGitlab\acvHeaderIconSep\@gitlab}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@stackoverflowid}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/\@stackoverflowid}{\faStackOverflow\acvHeaderIconSep\@stackoverflowname}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@linkedin}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\@linkedin}{\faLinkedinSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@linkedin}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@twitter}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://twitter.com/\@twitter}{\faTwitter\acvHeaderIconSep\@twitter}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \faSkype\acvHeaderIconSep\@skype%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@reddit}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.reddit.com/user/\@reddit}{\faReddit\acvHeaderIconSep\@reddit}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@xing}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.xing.com/profile/\@xing}{\faXingSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@xing}
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \@extrainfo%
        }%
    } \\[\acvHeaderAfterSocialSkip]%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
      {}%
      {\headerquotestyle{\@quote\\}\vspace{\acvHeaderAfterQuoteSkip}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  %\begin{minipage}[c]{\headerphotowidth}%
    %\ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoalign}{right}}{\raggedleft\drawphoto}{}
  %\end{minipage}
}
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter

\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=1.5cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.1cm, footskip=.5cm} 

\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts

\name{Isaac}{Kweon}
\mobile{(+01) 234 56789}

\email{test@example.com}

\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {Isaac Kweon~~~·~~~Résumé}
  {\thepage}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\renewcommand*{\makecvheader}[1][C]{%
  \newcommand*{\drawphoto}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{}{%
      \newlength{\photodim}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoshape}{circle}}%
        {\setlength{\photodim}{1.3cm}}%
        {\setlength{\photodim}{1.8cm}}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoedge}{edge}}%
        {\def\@photoborder{darkgray}}%
        {\def\@photoborder{none}}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[\@photoshape, draw=\@photoborder, line width=0.3mm, inner sep=\photodim, fill overzoom image=\@photo] () {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }
  \newlength{\headertextwidth}
  \newlength{\headerphotowidth}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{
    \setlength{\headertextwidth}{\textwidth}
    \setlength{\headerphotowidth}{0cm}
  }{%
    \setlength{\headertextwidth}{0.76\textwidth}
    \setlength{\headerphotowidth}{0.24\textwidth}
  }%
  %\begin{minipage}[c]{\headerphotowidth}%
    %\ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoalign}{left}}{\raggedright\drawphoto}{}
  %\end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\headertextwidth}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{L}}{\raggedright}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{\raggedleft}{\centering}}
    \headerfirstnamestyle{\@firstname}\headerlastnamestyle{{}\acvHeaderNameDelim\@lastname}%
    \\[\acvHeaderAfterNameSkip]%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@position}}{}{\headerpositionstyle{\@position\\[\acvHeaderAfterPositionSkip]}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@address}}{}{\headeraddressstyle{\@address\\[\acvHeaderAfterAddressSkip]}}%
    \headersocialstyle{%
      \newbool{isstart}%
      \setbool{isstart}{true}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \faMobile\acvHeaderIconSep\@mobile%
          \setbool{isstart}{false}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{mailto:\@email}{\faEnvelope\acvHeaderIconSep\@email}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{http://\@homepage}{\faHome\acvHeaderIconSep\@homepage}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@github}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://github.com/\@github}{\faGithubSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@github}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@gitlab}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://gitlab.com/\@gitlab}{\faGitlab\acvHeaderIconSep\@gitlab}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@stackoverflowid}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/\@stackoverflowid}{\faStackOverflow\acvHeaderIconSep\@stackoverflowname}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@linkedin}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\@linkedin}{\faLinkedinSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@linkedin}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@twitter}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://twitter.com/\@twitter}{\faTwitter\acvHeaderIconSep\@twitter}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \faSkype\acvHeaderIconSep\@skype%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@reddit}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.reddit.com/user/\@reddit}{\faReddit\acvHeaderIconSep\@reddit}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@xing}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.xing.com/profile/\@xing}{\faXingSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@xing}
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \@extrainfo%
        }%
    } \\[\acvHeaderAfterSocialSkip]%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
      {}%
      {\headerquotestyle{\@quote\\}\vspace{\acvHeaderAfterQuoteSkip}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  %\begin{minipage}[c]{\headerphotowidth}%
    %\ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoalign}{right}}{\raggedleft\drawphoto}{}
  %\end{minipage}
}
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document}

\makecvheader[C]

\cvsection{Education}

\begin{cventries}

\cventry %line 23  
   {Hebronstar Strategy Consultants}  
    {Intern (Research Assistant)}  
    {Seoul, S.Korea}  
    {May. 2017 - July. 2017}  
    {  
      \begin{cvitems}  
        \item {Researched about domestic start-up M\&A and IPO cases and discussed methods for expanding start-ups that are under investment}  
        \item {Communicated daily with 12 start-ups for weekly checkups and organized mentoring programs and Demo Day}\vspace{2mm}    
      \end{cvitems}
    }

\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf

[image]

without overful or underful boxes ...