# How to handle overfull/underfull hbox

Tags: vertical-alignment

i get an error message liks this

> Overfull \hbox (2.37161pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 137--138

or

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 136--147

My code

```latex
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{kurzpass.png}
\subcaption{Filterkurve eines typischen Kurzpassfilters\footnotemark}
\label{fig:kurzpass}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{langpass.png}
\subcaption{Filterkurve eines typischen Langpassfilters\footnotemark}
\label{fig:langpass}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\subref{fig:kurzpass} shows Figure1 and\subref{fig:langpass} shows Figure.}
\end{figure}
```

i do not get it

Comment: Related: [What does "overfull hbox" mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/5764); [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are *warning* messages, not *error* messages. Overfull `\hbox`es refer to having content that is too wide to fit within the text block width. In your case, you're placing two`subfigure`s next to one another - the `%` on the blank line between the two `subfigure`s set them in the same line - each of which has a width of `.7\textwidth`. That results in something that is wider than `\textwidth` (`1.4\textwidth` to be exact) and results in the overfull `\hbox` *warning*.

For placing two `subfigure`s next to one another, you're better off using `.5\linewidth` blocks, with the width of the internal images no more than `\linewidth` itself; `\linewidth` adjusts with the block it's placed in. `\centering` would also ensure that the content is horizontally centered.

Underfull `\hbox` warnings fall in a similar class in that there's not enough content to spread it across the text block sufficiently.