# TikZ Picture Does not get Printed

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, pdftex

When adding a figure made with TikZ, it seems like figures are not printed in some situations. For me, I currently cannot find out which are the exact circumstances causing this issue.

As minimal example, when I use `pdflatex` to compile

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[activity/.style={line width = 1pt, draw, shape = rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm}]
   \node[activity] (master) at (1, 0){master}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

test

\end{document}
```

The master-node gets printed as expected, but if I add `%` in front of test, the pdf just consists of `,,`.

A more real-life example is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, rounded corners, -latex']


\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[activity/.style={line width = 1pt, draw, shape = rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm}]
 
  \node[activity] (a) at (1, 0){a};
  \node[activity, below left= 0.5cm and -1.0cm of a]  (b) {b};
  \node[activity, below right = 0.5cm  and -1.0cm of a] (c) {c};
  \node[activity, below = 1.5cm of a] (d) {d};
  
  \node[activity, left=2cm of a, minimum height=4cm] (e) {
       Test e
   };
   
   \node[activity, right=2cm of e, minimum height=3cm] (f) {
       Test f
   };
   
   \node[activity, below=of f, minimum height=3cm] (g) {
       Test g
   };
   
   
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat}
\label{fig:branches}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  

\end{document}
```

Adding much text (3 paragraphs) after the picture solves this issue. In the log, there is `Overfull \vbox (11.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [3]`, therefore, the figure which is too big might be the reason of the warning ([What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them)). The only fix I currently see is changing the position of the figure or adding `\newpage`, which solves the issue for now but does not create a nice document.

Is this a known issue / is there some workaround or way I could further trace this behavior?

My version is:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```