# extra vertical spacing when new section starts in my research article, while working in the format of journal

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, sections-paragraphs, vertical-spacing

I am writing a research paper in a latex format of a journal, and facing extra spacing before and after of section ``Some properties for $\varphi_{m}$-convex function".
point out the problem please!

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{NSP1}
\usepackage{url,floatflt}
\usepackage{helvet,times}
\usepackage{psfig,graphics}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bf,hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\definecolor{rulecolor}{rgb}{0.0,0.54,0.44}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\topmargin=0.00cm

\def\sm{\smallskip}
\def\no{\noindent}

\def\firstpage{1}
\setcounter{page}{\firstpage}
\def\thevol{7}
\def\thenumber{?}
\def\theyear{2022}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\begin{document}
\titlefigurecaption{{\large \bf \rm Applied Mathematics \& Information Sciences }\\ {\it\small An International Journal}}
\title{On $\varphi_{m}-$Convex Functions.}
\author{Migwel Vivas Cortez\hyperlink{author1}{$^1$}, Muhammad Shoib Saleem\hyperlink{author2}{$^2$} and Razi Ur Rehman\hyperlink{author3}{$^3$}}
\institute{$^1$Departamento de Matem\'{a}ticas, Universidad Centroccidental Lisandro Alvarado, Barquisimeto, Venezuela\\
$^2$Department Of Mathematics, University Of Okara, Okara, Punjab, Pakistan\\
$^3$Department Of Mathematics, University Of Okara, Okara, Punjab, Pakistan}
\titlerunning{On $\varphi_{m}-$Convex Functions.}
\authorrunning{M. vivas, M. Shoib, R. Rehman}
%corresponding author email
\mail{razi.ur.rehman2089@gmail.com}
\received{...}
\revised{...}
\accepted{...}
\published{...}

\abstracttext{We will A for the convex function.. We give some basic properties for this notion. Furthermore, we set down proofs of Hermite-Hadamard type and Hermite-Hadamard-Fej\'{e}r type integral inequalities for this notion.
}

\keywords{Convex function, $\varphi-$convex functions, A, B, , Hermite-Hadamard type inequalities and Hermite-Hadamard-Fej\'{e}r type integral inequalities.}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Through out the paper, we will use the symbol $``\kappa"$ for convex function (and its generalizations). Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function of two real variables unless we shall specify otherwise.

In the present section, we give some basic definitions and inequalities, which already exist in the literature, we use them through the paper. In section \ref{sec2}, we investigate some a \cite{6}. By using one of the four forms and \cite{6}, we introduce our new notion C, which is generalizations of convex, A and B. Let we shall see later. The remaining sections are clear by their title.

The following definition \cite{1}, \cite{2}, is the base of the literature:\\
$\kappa:A\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is known as \textbf{\textit{convex function}} if,
\begin{equation}
\kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq\,r \kappa(u)+(1-r) \kappa(v)
\end{equation}
for every $u,v\in A\,\, and\,\,r\in[0,1].$

An inequality \cite{3}, \cite{4}, which is very basic and fundamental for the literature:\\
If $\kappa:A\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex function and $p,q\in A$ with $p<q$. Then
\begin{equation}\label{hhi}
\kappa\bigg(\frac{p+q}{2}\bigg)\leq\frac{1}{q-p}\int_{p}^{q}\kappa(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\leq \frac{\kappa(p)+\kappa(q)}{2}
\end{equation}
is called \textbf{\textit{Hermite-Hadamard inequality}}.

Another inequality \cite{5}, which is the generalization of above inequality (\ref{hhi}) was derived in the year 1905 Leopold Fej\'{e}r, as the following:\\
If $\kappa:[p,q]\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, and $\chi:[p,q]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is symmetric about $\frac{p+q}{2}$, integrable and non-negative. Then
\begin{align}\label{hhfi}
\kappa\bigg(\frac{p+q}{2}\bigg)\int_{p}^{q}\chi(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\leq\frac{1}{q-p}\int_{p}^{q} \kappa(u) \chi(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\leq \notag\\
\frac{\kappa(p)+\kappa(q)}{2}\int_{p}^{q} \chi(u)\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
is known as \textbf{\textit{Hermite-Hadamard-Fej\'{e}r inequality}}.

G. Toader \cite{6} , generalize the convex function as $m-$convex function, in the year 1984, as the following:\\
$\kappa:[0,q)\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $q>0$ be an \textbf{\textit{$m-$convex function}} if,
\begin{eqnarray}\label{mcon}
\kappa(ru+m(1-r)v)\leq r \kappa(u)+m(1-r) \kappa(v)
\end{eqnarray}
holds for every $u,v\in[0,q)$ and $r,m\in[0,1]$.

M. Eshaghi Gordji, M. Rostamian Delavar, M. De La Sen \cite{7}, generalize convex function as $\varphi-$convex function,in the year 2016,  as the following:\\
let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function of two real variables then, a function $\kappa:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called \textbf{\textit{$\varphi-$convex}} if,
\begin{eqnarray}\label{phicons}
\kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq\,\kappa(v)+r\varphi\Big(\kappa(u),\kappa(v)\Big).
\end{eqnarray}
Note that $\eta-$convex function \cite{10} and $\varphi-$convex function \cite{8} are the same notions. So we can also termed $\varphi_{m}-$convex function as $\eta_{m}-$convex function 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  sec 2   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Basic Definitions.}\label{sec2}
In this section we investigate different  forms of $\varphi-$convex function. One of these forms is require for our new generalization . We give some important remarks and examples for our new notion $\varphi_m-$convex function.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Now we give following four forms of $\varphi-$convex function, or it can be define in the following four different ways.
\begin{definition} \label{phicon}
Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then a function $\kappa:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called \textbf{\textit{$\varphi-$convex}} if, 
\begin{align}
& \kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq\,r \label{phicon1} \\ 
& \kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq\,(1-r) \label{phicon2}\\
& \kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq\,\kappa  \label{phicon3}\\
&\kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq\,\kappa \label{phicon4}
\end{align}
for every $r\in[0,1]\,$ and\, for every $u,v\in A$. Above inequality (\ref{phicon3}) is same as inequality (\ref{phicons}).
\end{definition}

The above definitions will become classical convex functions if, we take\\
$\varphi(u,v)=v$ in (\ref{phicon1})\\
$\varphi(u,v)=u$ in (\ref{phicon2})\\
$\varphi(u,v)=u-v$ in (\ref{phicon3})\\
$\varphi(u,v)=v-u$ in (\ref{phicon4}).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% rem 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{remark}
All the four definitions are similar to each other. Lets see! if we set K in inequality (\ref{phicon1}), we get inequality (\ref{phicon4}) and if we set G in inequality (\ref{phicon2}), we get inequality (\ref{phicon3}), where H is another function of two real variables.
\end{remark}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{definition}
If we take equalities in-place of inequalities in Definition \ref{phicon}, we get \textbf{\textit{$\varphi-$affine functions}}, for all $r,u,v\in\mathbb{R}$. Clearly we will also get classical affine functions.
\end{definition}

We give one example to illustrate $\varphi-$convex function \ref{phicon1}.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Example 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{example}
Let $\kappa(u)=u^2$ which is convex. If $\varphi(u,v)=2v+u$, then $\kappa$ is $\varphi-$ convex.
\end{example}
\textbf{Solution}.
\begin{align*}
 \kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\\
& =(ru+(1-r)v)^2\\
& =r^2\\
& \leq ru)\\
& = ru)\\ 
&= r
\end{align*}
Which shows $\kappa$ is $\varphi-$convex.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Now we give different forms of $\varphi-$quasi convex function.
\begin{definition} \label{phiqcon}
Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then a function $\kappa:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called \textbf{\textit{$\varphi-$quasi convex}} if, 
\begin{align}
& \kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq\ A \label{phiqcon1}\\
& \kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq A\label{phiqcon2}\\
& \kappa(ru+(1-r)v)\leq A          \label{phiqcon3}\\
&\kappa(ru+(1-r)v)A  \label{phiqcon4}
\end{align}
for every $r\in[0,1]\,$ and\, for every $u,v\in A$.
\end{definition}
The above definitions will become classical quasi convex function if, we take\\
$\varphi(u,v)=v$ in \ref{phiqcon1}\\
$\varphi(u,v)=u$ in \ref{phiqcon2}\\
$\varphi(u,v)=u-v$ in \ref{phiqcon3}\\
$\varphi(u,v)=v-u$ in \ref{phiqcon4}.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{definition}
If we reverse the inequalities in Definition \ref{phicon} and Definition \ref{phiqcon} then, we get \textbf{\textit{$\varphi-$concave}} and \textbf{\textit{$\varphi-$quasi concave}} functions.
\end{definition}

Through the rest of this paper, let $[0,q]=I\subset\mathbb{R}, q>0, [0,+\infty)=J\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $m,r\in[0,1]$, unless we specify otherwise.

Now we come to our main concern and construct A.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 5 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{definition}\label{phihm}
$\kappa:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is \textbf{\textit{convex function}} with respect to non-negative $\varphi$  if, 
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\kappa(r\\
&r\kappa(u)
\end{split}
\end{align}
for every $u,v\in I$ and for every $r\in(0,1)$.
\end{definition}

we are denoting the set of all A as a class V.

If we choose K , we come to B \ref{mcon}.

If we choose K, we come to C \ref{phicon} (actually $\varphi-$convexity \cite{8}) for the interval $I$.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 6 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{definition}
If we reverse the inequality in Definition \ref{phihm}, then we get \textbf{\textit{concave function}}.
\end{definition}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Example 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

We give one example to illustrate our $\varphi_{m}-$convex function.
\begin{example}
let $\kappa(u)=u^2$ which is convex. If $\varphi(u,v)=2v+u$ then, $\kappa$ is $\varphi_{m}-$ convex.
\end{example}
\textbf{Solution}.
\begin{align*}
\kappa(ru+m(1-r)v)\\
& =(ru\\
& =r^2\\
& \leq r\\
& = r\\
&= r.
\end{align*}
Which shows $\kappa$ is $\varphi_{m}-$ convex.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% section 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\section{Operations Which Preserve $\varphi_{m}$-Convex Function.}
In the present section, we shall give some basic properties for our notion $\varphi_{m}-$ convex function.  we first give various conditions for the function $\varphi$. We use these concepts often in our results.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 9 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{definition}
We say that $\varphi$ is,
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item\label{2} additive if, $\varphi(u_{1},v_{1})+\varphi(u_{2},v_{2})=\varphi(u_{1}+u_{2},v_{1}+v_{2})$ for all $u_{1},u_{2},v_{1},v_{2}\in\mathbb{R}.$\\
\item\label{1} non-negatively homogeneous if, $\varphi(\beta u,\beta v)=\beta\varphi(u,v)$ for all $u,v\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta\geq 0.$\\
\item no-negatively linear if, it satisfies conditions \ref{1} and \ref{2}.
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
The following is trivial fact of calculus for function of two variables:

Let limit of $u_n$ and $v_n$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(u_n,v_n)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n,\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n).$$
\end{document}
```

The class can be found [here](https://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/pages/j8jz7x4m8f316e.zip).

Comment: I am not more familiar with latex,

Comment: I can just compile this code only in format of latex,

Comment: Sorry, but the question is quite unclear. Vertical space before and after sections is a common feature of most classes and usual in all kind of documents. And if you are using the publisher's class for that journal, I would expect, that it this space is wanted. If you mean something different, please extend your code to a complete LaTeX document from `\documentclass` over `\begin{document}` until `\end{document}`, and explicitly explain, what should be different for this code.

Comment: If you are using a class (which you do not reference as in `\documentclass...`) provided by the journal then presumably the spacing is what they want. If you are using one of the standard classes then show that in your MWE. In any case how are we expected to know what you mean about  "undesired spacing" --- too large, too small, off the page ...?

Comment: Sometimes, especially in two-column documents, undesired spacing around or within sections can occur because LaTeX has trouble fitting the start of a new section below the previous section, which can leave large gaps. In that case the only proper solution is to rewrite the text of the section to be either shorter or longer, or move a table or figure to a different page if it is preventing the flow of the sections.

Comment: However, if it is for a journal (as opposed to a conference), then usually the journal publisher will take care of the final layout of the paper, which means that you can submit it even if the layout is not perfect.

Comment: Dear @Marijn I have added the total code before the document begins in my question, the document is two sided and gaps are very large

Comment: @razich I'm not sure if I understand the problem fully. When I compile your code (after adding `\end{document}`) I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdP06.png. This shows a bit of a gap before the new section but not _very_ big. Is this indeed the gap that you are asking about, or do you get different output for the code you provided here?

Comment: your compiling is fine.

Comment: but when I compile there are so big gaps before and after the new section starts and gap is still so big before the Definition 1. I think the the is in between the document, thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: @razich so if I understand correctly, your output has a problem while the output linked in my previous comment does not have that problem? In that case you will need to add more contents to the code in your question until the problem appears. Of course if you don't want to show the real text from your paper then you can change it into something else, but it is important that you add code that actually shows the problem, so we can try to fix it.

Comment: @razich I tried your new code with the three sections but I don't see any large gaps. Section 1 fits on page 1, section 2 fits on page 2, and section 3 is about 25% of page 3. Is this different for you? Maybe you can add a screenshot to your post?

Comment: @razich Do have the same version of `NSP1.cls` that can be found in the linked archive? I'm asking, because your code without the needed `\PassOptionsToPackage` (see my answer) does not compile without errors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the class seems to be broken. It needs

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{color}
```

before `\documentclass`, otherwise the used color `Green` in line 573 of the class file, is undefined.

However with this, there isn't a lot of white space before and after the section, only 21dd before and 10.5dd below. If you want to change this you have to copy:

```
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-21dd plus-4pt minus-4pt}{10.5dd plus 4pt
     minus4pt}{\large\bfseries}}
```

from line 1624–1626 of the class file into your document preamble, add `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after and change the values, e.g., using:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{color}
\documentclass[10pt]{NSP1}
\usepackage{url,floatflt}
\usepackage{helvet,times}
\usepackage{psfig,graphics}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bf,hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\definecolor{rulecolor}{rgb}{0.0,0.54,0.44}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\topmargin=0.00cm

\def\sm{\smallskip}
\def\no{\noindent}

\def\firstpage{1}
\setcounter{page}{\firstpage}
\def\thevol{16}
\def\thenumber{6}
\def\theyear{2022}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}    

\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-10dd plus-4pt minus-4pt}{5dd plus 4pt
     minus4pt}{\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{example}
    let $\kappa(u)=u^2$ which is convex. If $\varphi(u,v)=2v+u$ then, $\kappa$ is $\varphi_{m}-$ convex.
    \end{example}
    \textbf{Solution}.
    \begin{align*}
    \kappa(ru+m(1-r)v)\\
    & =(ru+m(1-r)v)^2\\
    & =r^2u^2+m^2(1-r)^2v^2+rm(1-r)2uv\\
    & \leq ru^2+m(1-r)v^2+m(1-r)(u^2+v^2)\\
    & = ru^2+m(1-r)(u^2+2v^2)\\
    &= r\kappa(u)+m(1-r)\varphi\Big(\kappa(u),\kappa(v)\Big).
    \end{align*}
    Which shows $\kappa$ is $\varphi_{m}-$ convex.
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% section 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    \section{Some properties for $\varphi_{m}$-convex function.}

    In the present section, we shall give some basic properties for our notion $\varphi_{m}-$ convex function.  we first give various conditions for the function $\varphi$. We use these concepts often in our results.
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 9 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{definition}
    We say that $\varphi$ is,
    
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

This would result in

[image]

However, such changes are usually not welcome by publishers of journals, that provide their own classes. So you should not do it.

But maybe your code doesn't really show your problem. Maybe it occurs only with column breaks? In this case, unbreakable material like boxes could result in overstretching vertical white spaces. In this case, you will see [`underfull \vbox` messages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/277964) in the log-file. You can, e.g., either add, `\newpage` commands to force page breaks without stretching or use `\raggedbottom`. But `\raggedbottom` would also stop vertical alignment of the last line, if it does not break anything.

You can use this example to experiment with the alternatives:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{color}
\documentclass[10pt]{NSP1}
\usepackage{url,floatflt}
\usepackage{helvet,times}
\usepackage{psfig,graphics}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bf,hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\definecolor{rulecolor}{rgb}{0.0,0.54,0.44}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\topmargin=0.00cm

\def\sm{\smallskip}
\def\no{\noindent}

\def\firstpage{1}
\setcounter{page}{\firstpage}
\def\thevol{16}
\def\thenumber{6}
\def\theyear{2022}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}    

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom% try without it to compare
    \begin{example}
    let $\kappa(u)=u^2$ which is convex. If $\varphi(u,v)=2v+u$ then, $\kappa$ is $\varphi_{m}-$ convex.
    \end{example}
    \textbf{Solution}.
    \begin{align*}
    \kappa(ru+m(1-r)v)\\
    & =(ru+m(1-r)v)^2\\
    & =r^2u^2+m^2(1-r)^2v^2+rm(1-r)2uv\\
    & \leq ru^2+m(1-r)v^2+m(1-r)(u^2+v^2)\\
    & = ru^2+m(1-r)(u^2+2v^2)\\
    &= r\kappa(u)+m(1-r)\varphi\Big(\kappa(u),\kappa(v)\Big).
    \end{align*}
    Which shows $\kappa$ is $\varphi_{m}-$ convex.
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% section 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    \section{Some properties for $\varphi_{m}$-convex function.}

    In the present section, we shall give some basic properties for our notion $\varphi_{m}-$ convex function.  we first give various conditions for the function $\varphi$. We use these concepts often in our results.
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% def 9 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{definition}
    We say that $\varphi$ is,
    
  \end{definition}

  \lipsum[1-2]
  % \newpage% This would be an alternative to \raggedbottom above.
  \rule{8cm}{5cm}
  
\end{document}
```

Here the first image shows the result without `\raggedbottom` and the second one the result with `\raggedbottom`:

[image: with underfull \vbox]

[image: with \raggedbottom]

However, because usually the publisher will do the final editing, such changes are not needed and using `\raggedbottom` is usually not allowed.

Comment: With your redefinition it seems that the section titles become smaller?

Comment: @Marijn Argh, the class has two definitions of `\section`. Who writes such ugly code??? I've change it to the second one, now. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @Marijn I have uploaded the complete code please guide.