# Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

Tags: bad-box

The following is the example code which just displays title "ABC" and i still get the Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) at line 1, \documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic, Numbered]{sn-jnl} \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\title[Article Title]{ABC}
\maketitle
\end{document}

Any help on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: don't show only a piece of code. Show a short but complete example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: My wild guess would be that you are using `\\ ` incorrectly.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/107497

Comment: The class is badly written and the `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000)` warning is issued when *every* page is shipped out, followed by `Overfull \vbox (1.44444pt too high)` (with possibly a different length). Live with it.

Comment: Are you required to use this documentclass?  If so, ask whoever is requiring you to fix the class.  If not, then I would recommend a different documentclass.  (And notice also the code formatting that egreg used in a previous version of this post, so that we can see you code more clearly.)