# Prevent Overfull \hbox

Tags: line-breaking, overfull

I am new to LaTeX. Recently I have taken it up to do some math note taking on my laptop.
I have found a template which seems quite useful for this. Nonetheless, after some time spent doing the set up, there seems to be a problem with constant overfulls in certain parts of my text.

This template I am using includes some custom sections like \thm for theorems or \prop for propositions. However, whenever I use \ex or \rmkb for examples and remarks respectively, I always run across overfull hbox. It seems like those are not set up for breaking lines, somehow? I have had no problems with other parts but rather just these two. Could you help me figure out how can I modify them in order to avoid this problem? Below you can find the code where it is defined (sorry for my major lack of knowledge in LaTeX terminology, I have just discovered it a few days ago and I am still learning a lot).

```
% Remark
\NewDocumentCommand{\rmk}{+m}{
    {\it \color{blue!50!white}#1}
}

\newenvironment{remark}{
    \par
    \vspace{5pt}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        {\par\noindent{\textbf{Observación.}}}
        \tcolorbox[blanker,breakable,left=5mm,
        before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,
        borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{cyan!10!white}]
}{
        \endtcolorbox
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{5pt}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rmkb}{+m}{
    \begin{remark}
        #1
    \end{remark}
}
```

Similarly here is how \ex is defined,

```
% Example
\newenvironment{example}{%
    \par
    \vspace{5pt}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \noindent\textbf{Example.}
        \tcolorbox[blanker,breakable,left=5mm,parbox=false,
        before upper={\parindent15pt},
        after skip=10pt,
        borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{cyan!10!white}]
}{%
        \endtcolorbox
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{5pt}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ex}{+m}{
    \begin{example}
        #1
    \end{example}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Edit. Here is an image that represents what my problem is.

[image: 'Observacion' aka 'Remark' going beyond the margin]

Another example. This seems to happen consistently with all 'Remark' boxes.

[image: Second example!]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! You don't actually have to do anything about overfull hboxes—even experienced users get such warnings. TeX calculates something known as *badness*, which (very loosely) corresponds to how ugly a box is. If TeX thinks a box would look more aesthetically pleasing if it had less stuff inside it, it'll raise an overfull warning (again, very loosely). However, for human readers, the overfull-ness is often barely perceptible. As a result, unless you see a problem involving too much stuff with your own eyes, there's no need to worry.

Comment: You may also be interested in this: [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them)

Comment: Hello, @gz839918! Thank you for your answer. Perhaps I have not been clear with my problem (most likely), but what I am seeing is that specifically in these examples and remarks sections, the text is going beyond the margin. I thought that is that overfull hbox meant. I'd like to somehow force the margin, because all of the other boxes I use such as theorems or propositions have a certain margin they respect, instead here they go over that shared margen with other sections.
Is there anything else I could share which would make the question more clear, maybe?

Comment: Moreover, regarding your linked post, I had read it before but I could not quite get the 'manual route' to work on my end. For example, in the first image I have just edited into the post, if I write res\-petando the output is still respe-tando. I'd much rather have LaTeX completely force the linebreaks in order to maintain the same margins as the above colourful boxes, is there perhaps any way to do that?

Comment: It looks to me like the `\noindent` needs to precede the remark, i.e., before the `minipage`.  Unless you have set `\parindent=0pt`, there will be an indent applied before anything that shifts into horizontal mode, like `minipage`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's it! Thank you! It works perfectly now. Just to make sure I did it right, you meant to delete the \noindent before \textbf and rather just place it as \noindent\begin{minipage}... right?

Comment: @BelowAverageCProgrammer -- Yes, that's essentially what I meant.  But I don't remember if the default *inside* a `minipage` is always to start with no `\parindent`.  So you may want to test that as well.  But for sure, remember that `\noindent` *inside* a `minipage` has no effect *outside* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there's no MWE here, and the document class is unknown, the context makes the problem clear.

Remember that in most document classes, the `\parindent` is nonzero.  And that indent will be applied to anything that follows a paragraph break (whether specified by a blank line or `\par`).

In this question, a `minipage` follows `\par`, so the whole `minipage` will be indented.  So the fix is to precede the `\minipage` by `\noindent`.  Putting `\noindent` as the first thing inside the `minipage` will negate a possible indentation *inside* the `\minipage` (usually there isn't any in that position), but it won't back up to before the `\minipage`; that has already happened, and TeX doesn't go backwards.

Remember: If something has already been processed, you can't go back.  TeX is "one-way".