why doesn't latex generate a linebreak between two consecutive large tables?
I generate latex code (MCQ automatically generated using python), most of the time it works well but sometimes overflows occur, and I can't understand why.
This is a very simplificated example :
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
        Some text some text some text some text.\end{tabular}} \quad \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
        Some text some text some text.\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}} 
\end{document}


However, slightly enlarging the first table removes the overflow.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}        
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
        Some text some text some text some text NEW.\end{tabular}} \quad \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
        Some text some text some text.\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}} 
\end{document}


So:

Why is latex breaking the line in the first case, and not in the other one ?
Is there a way to force latex to adopt the second strategy, without adding a manual \linebreak?

(I tried enclosing both tables inside a flushleft environment, with no effect. Suggesting a linebreak with \linebreak[3] between the two tables has no effect either.)

There are several limitations for line breaks in justified text and your two boxes are in a justified paragraph. You can use \raggedright or a flushleft environment or a sloppypar environment to either use not justified text or allow much more line breaks and extended spacing.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean-why-is-there-a-black-mark-at-the-end-of-a-line and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them and similar questions.

BTW: Your \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}…\end{minipage}} is already wider than \linewidth. Unfortunately, you have not taken the two \fboxsep and \fboxrule into account.

I cannot reproduce your:

I tried enclosing both tables inside a flushleft environment, with no effect.

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}        
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{flushleft}
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
        Some text some text some text some text.\end{tabular}} \quad \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
        Some text some text some text.\end{tabular}}\end{flushleft}\end{minipage}} 
\end{document}

results in:

but still has an overfull \hbox.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}        
\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}\raggedright
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
        Some text some text some text some text.\end{tabular}} \quad \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
        Some text some text some text.\end{tabular}}\end{minipage}} 
\end{document}

would solve this additional problem by taking the two \fboxsep and two \fboxrule of \fbox and also the paragraph indent into account.
For more information about overfull \hbox warnings see: What does "overfull hbox" mean? (Why is there a black mark at the end of a line?)

OK, I enclosed all the code inside a \begin{flushleft} and \end{flushleft}, but I didn't realize that the minipage environment resets the justification behaviour, so I must put it inside the minipage environment. Thanks!

By the way, do you know why adding text in the first table causes latex to insert a linebreak, but adding the same text into the second table doesn't generate a linebreak, though the overflow is the same?

@pTyX See the paragraph breaking calculations in The TeX book.
