# Overfull \hbox warning when using tabular

Tags: tables, boxes, warnings

I keep getting this warning

```
 Overfull \hbox (0.63303pt too wide) in paragraph at lines xxx--xxx`
```

wherever I have this line in the code

```
 \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
```

It does not stop me from working on and creating documents  but I was just wondering why I keep getting that.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it to be honest.The difference is probably too small to see at 0.6330pt wide. What class are you using? Most classes will use an \hfuzz figure of at least 1pt to avoid such messages.

Comment: Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean

Comment: @Yiannis: Right, one doesn't have to worry, but if you have lots of these messages, then the more severe ones might get lost. So I consider it a good idea to try and avoid such minor messages.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem (including the preamble).

Answer (score 23):

I assume you get this warning because your tabular is (a little bit) wider than your `\textwidth`. Solutions include:

- enlarging the `\textwidth` a little
- narrowing down the `tabular` by a little
- adding `\hfuzz=0.64pt` somewhere in the preamble

The `\hfuzz` setting specifies the maximum amount of box-overflow *before* a warning message will be issued.

Answer (score 9):

use this tabular definition:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm} @{}}
```

the definition of a row is

```
|\tabcolsep|2cm|\tabcolsep|\tabcolsep|4cm|\tabcolsep|...|\tabcolsep|
```

The `@{}` remove the `\tabcolsep` at the beginning and end of the tabular row.

Comment: Herbert, can you explain what this does?

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: This answer is fantastic. This explains why width warnings start to show up before the hbox visually overflows. Been through a few forums looking for a reason why the warnings come up too early, and this explains the underlying cause perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Using the new [adjustbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package of Martin Scharrer, you can place your `tabular` inside of an `adjustbox`. This package will shrink your tabular to fit to the `\textwidth` (and to the `\textheight`, if that should be necessary) without distortion of the text (or any other content in the box; `keepaspectratio` is the key).

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={\textheight},keepaspectratio}%
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
    ...
\end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
```

But because it *resizes* the tabular, it is better suited for cases like

```
 \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
```

For columns with fixed width Herbert's solution is more appropriate, which removes horizontal space at the beginning and end of a row.

Comment: While that will work, it will mask the underlying problem (cf. Herbert's answer).

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing this out. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

One thing that might be useful is using the `\resizebox` command to scale your environment to the available width of the page. It saves having to manually fiddle with the sizes to make it perfect but can result in text distortion when used on an environment that is far too small/large.

In the case of your tabular environment you would uses it as such:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {%
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
%Fill table with data
\end{tabular}%
}
```

This will scale the tabular environment to the exact width of the page, with (in this case) negligible text distortion.

Comment: I've added two `%` characters that avoid spurious spaces.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've only used the command for a report where whitespace was desirable so I didn't consider that.

Comment: To prevent text distortion, I would advise the use of the (new) adjustbox package instead of `\resizebox` (please see my answer).

Comment: While that will work, it will mask the underlying problem (cf. Herbert's answer).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand tex very well, but this is my favorite answer and also the one provided on wikibooks.org http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Controlling_table_size