# How to suppress overfull hbox warnings up to some maximum?

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

I want LaTeX not to give warnings for overfull hboxes up to some maximum of say 2 pts. How to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/overfull-hbox-warning/6241#6241)  is helpful to you?

Comment: So is this a duplicate?

Comment: Please take a look at the question that meep.meep has suggested as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate as this question explicitly asks for a solution to manually change the warning whereas the first question is about the general explanation/understanding of this warning. It is right, though, that the answers overlap. Does that qualify as a duplicate?

Comment: Not a duplicate: someone searching for an answer to my question will never/not easily find the answer meep.meep provides a link to

Comment: @willem is exactly right: this question shows up in the first few results for a search on "suppress overfull hbox warning" and gave me a solution right away.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Tested it, works! See also [this Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/hfuzz).

```
\documentclass{article}

\hfuzz=5.002pt 

\begin{document}
looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
\end{document}
```

where `\hfuzz=length` is a parameter that allows hbox's to be overfull by `length` before an overfull error occurs.

Comment: Please always add a short explanation to your solutions even if you have added a hyperlink to such explanations. An answer should be properly self-contained. Something like "Using `\hfuzz` allows `\hbox` to be overfull to the given amount before a warning is raised".

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: done.

Comment: Thanks! But the `[]` are confusing.

Comment: This answer does not work in this MWE: `\documentclass{article}\hfuzz=100pt\begin{document}\parbox{1em}{Long}\end{document}`: "Overfull \hbox (11.8056pt too wide) in paragraph". You would have to use `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\parbox{1em}{\hfuzz=100pt Long}\end{document}`