# overfull vbox warning disable

Tags: warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to suppress overfull hbox warnings up to some maximum?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13715/how-to-suppress-overfull-hbox-warnings-up-to-some-maximum)

I get many warnings like

```
Overfull \vbox (13.88728pt too high) detected at line 250
```

How can I remove/disable the warnings? I don't care about `13pt`'s of overfull. I believe it has to do with how I use `mdframed` and page breaks. It's not a big deal to have `13pt`s over. I'd like to either completely remove the warning or allow around `30pt`s of overfull for vbox before the warning occurs.

I've tried various things like

```
\pretolerance=10000  
\tolerance=10000 
\hbadness=10000  
\vbadness=10000  
\emergencystretch=30pt
```

But none have any effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the value of `\vfuzz` in the preamble:

```
\vfuzz=30pt
```

`\vfuzz` controls the maximum overrun before overfull vbox messages occur. However, in my opinion, admitting `30pt` overfull might be excessive.