# Suppress natbib warnings

Tags: pdftex, natbib, warnings

The output of pdflatex is filled with lines like this:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `lee2004calder' on page 15 undefined on input
line 207.
```

I'm aware that the citation is undefined, and at some future point I'll find the warning helpful, but it's currently cluttering pdflatex output. I'd like a `no-warn` option that I can enable while I'm not interested in natbib issues, and disable at a later point. The [natbib documentation](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) doesn't appear to have anything similar.

How can I suppress these warnings?

A [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66958/how-do-you-suppress-specific-warnings-generated-by-pdflatex) has no useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility; the [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package was used to patch the internal commands `\NAT@citexnum`, `\NAT@citex` and `\nocite` and suppress the warnings they generate for undefined citations. Use `\NoWarnNat` to suppress the warnings; comment-out the command to activate the warnings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\NoWarnNat{
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citexnum}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citex}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\nocite}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\NoWarnNat% comment-out this line to activate the warnings

\begin{document}

\nocite{bbbb}
\cite{aaaa}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```