# Suppress fontaxes warnings

Tags: fonts, macros, warnings

I'm using [MyriadPro](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mdsymbol). When compiling, I'm getting a lot of fontaxes warnings:

> Package fontaxes Warning: I don't know how to decode
>   (fontaxes)                family `cmr' on input line 632.

I would like to suppress these. A [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123361/suppress-natbib-warnings) about natbib was similar, but I'm unsure how to extend that answer to this specific case.

I've found [this](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/hg/typeface/rev/0.1) [7.1206-7.1227 of `typeface.sty`], which appears to do what I'm after, but inserting the below fragment doesn't work:

```
   \ifdef{\fa@warn@undecodable}{
     \renewcommand*\fa@warn@undecodable[1]{}
     \TF@PackageInfoNoLine{Silenced fontaxes command %
        \string\fa@warn@undecodable}
   }{}
   \ifdef{\fontaxes@warn@undecodable}{
     \renewcommand*\fontaxes@warn@undecodable[1]{}
     \TF@PackageInfoNoLine{Silenced fontaxes command %
     \string\fontaxes@warn@undecodable}
   }{}
```

This still produces the errors.

**How can I disable the fontaxes warnings?**

Comment: @Werner Wow, that's perfect. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

1. Following some guidelines in [How do I get rid of particular `pdftex` warning message?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25047/5764), the [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) provides some assistance. By adding

   ```
   \usepackage{silence}% http://ctan.org/pkg/silence
   \WarningFilter{fontaxes}{I don't know how to decode}
   ```

   to you document preamble, `silence` will filter out warnings from the [`fontaxes` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontaxes) that starts with "I don't know how to decode".
2. Examine the code contained in [`fontaxes.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontaxes/fontaxes.dtx) in search of the warning to find:

   ```
   \newcommand*\fontaxes@warn@undecodable[1]{%
     \PackageWarning{fontaxes}{I don't know how to decode\MessageBreak #1}}
   ```

   This is the command that spits out the warning message. You can silence the macro by making it gobble it's argument:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \let\fontaxes@warn@undecodable\@gobble
   \makeatother
   ```