# fontaxes warning with llncs.sty

Tags: fonts, warnings, libertine, lncs

Springer's LNCS class (found in [llncs.zip](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip)) gives a `fontaxes` warning when I try to load the following additional fonts:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
Hello
%\subsection{Hello} % uncomment this line to see warning
\end{document}
```

Presumably `fontaxes` is being used internally somewhere, although I don't actually know what `fontaxes` does; introducing a `subsection` seems to be sufficient to cause the warning, as the code above shows.

Although I can [suppress the warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127063), I would rather fix the problem, or at least have someone convince me it's a non-problem.

Comment: `llncs.sty` is a LaTeX2.09 style, not a class, and doesn't work with `\documentclass`. If I download `llncs.cls` from the Springer website and run your example I do get the message: I guess this is what you meant? As the class is for a publisher, I'd be very wary of making _any_ font changes or indeed loading any packages you do not absolutely require.

Comment: The subsection is in bold and fontaxes (loaded by libertine) is trying to change bold math but can't with iwona. The warning is imho not a problem but it is always possible that the code doesn't take in to account some special font setup or that some font package you load does something unusual so keep an eye on the math.

Comment: @JosephWright Re. class vs. style - correct. I'll update the question.

Comment: The problem appears also with the `article` class as soon as one tries to do `{\boldmath$a$}`. The `iwona` package is not compatible with `fontaxes` that's required by `libertine`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer @egreg Useful information, thanks. (I've been using these packages together for many months but only ran into this problem when I started using `llncs.cls`, so I guess I just haven't been using both math.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `iwona` sets the math fonts in a way that's incompatible with `fontaxes`, which is required by `libertine`. The warning does not depend on the class, as it shows also with the `article` class as soon as one issues

```
\boldmath
```

which `llncs.cls` does when section titles are typeset.

You get the same result, with no warning or error, by defining directly the math fonts as done in `iwona.sty`, with the necessary small changes.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{libertine}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{iwonam}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{iwona}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{iwona}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {bold}{OT1}{iwonam} {b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {bold}{OML}{iwona} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {bold}{OMS}{iwona}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{iwona}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{iwona}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{iwona}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{OT1}{iwona}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{OT1}{iwona}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{iwona}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{OT1}{iwona}{bx}{it}


\begin{document}

Hello

$\sin\pi=0$

{\boldmath$a+b=c$}

\subsection{Hello}
\end{document}
```

However, text in Linux Libertine and math in Iwona is a real punch in the eye.