# Font shape not available with `newpx`

Tags: compiling, bold, font-encodings, small-caps, shapes

Have a document with `newpx` and use `bold`, `small caps` and `large` text (with MikTeX 2.9).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[largesc]{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
Normal

\textbf{Bold textbf}

{\bfseries Bold bfseries}

\large{large}

\large{\textbf{large Bold}}

\large{\textbf{\textsc{large Bold Small Caps}}}
\end{document}
```

MikTeX throws these *LaTeX Font Info* in the log file.

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/n' tried instead on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.0pt on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/n' tried instead on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.0pt on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/bx/sc' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/sc' tried instead on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/sc' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.0pt on input line 14.
```

Two questions:

1) Why is bold extended (`bx`) called, when I use `textbf` (`b`)? When using `bfseries`, `bx` is not called and no *LeTeX Font Info* is triggered!

2) Can I improve the compiling speed somehow, by getting rid of all the *LaTeX Font Info*, especially when having a large Thesis document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel value of `\bfdefault` is `bx`, but the NewPX fonts use `b` and, indeed, in the `t1zpltlf.fd` file you find lines such as

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{zpltlf}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * zpltlf/b/n}{}
```

When you do `\bfseries` (which is implicitly done when `\textbf` is processed), LaTeX will set the font series to `bx` and so there will be a “silent substitution” (declared by `ssub`), which will nevertheless recorded in the log file as “Font Info”.

If the substitution had been declared with `sub`, instead of a “Font Info” message only in the log file you'd get a “Font Warning” also on the console.

If *all* fonts you use in boldface series have a `b` series denotator instead of `bx`, you can do

```
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
```

in the preamble. But I don't recommend doing it: it just reduces the number of “Font Info” message without giving a real benefit.

With the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[largesc]{newpxtext}

\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}

\begin{document}
Normal

\textbf{Bold textbf}

{\bfseries Bold bfseries}

{\large large\par}

{\large\textbf{large Bold}\par}

{\large\textbf{\textsc{large Bold Small Caps}}\par}
\end{document}
```

the log file will have

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.0pt on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.0pt on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zpltlf/b/sc' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.0pt on input line 17.
```

The information is recorded just once, when a font is loaded for the first time.

As an aside, note that `\large`, like all font size declarations, is not a command with an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You get the message with `\bfseries` too. But in a document you get it only once, as from then on latex knows that this combination of font setting should be substituated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[largesc]{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
Normal

{\bfseries Bold bfseries}

blblb

{\bfseries Bold bfseries}

\end{document}
```

gives message for line 6 but not for line 10:

```
 ... scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 6.
```

In your example the `\textbf` came first and so triggered the message.

One can silence the messages, but I doubt that you would win much.

Answer (score 0):

1) These two commands are not entirely identical. You can think of it like this*: `\bfseries` says, "switch to the default bold typeface from here on, whatever that might be." That may or may not be extended depending on what font family you are using. If your font family does not contain a bold shape LaTeX would complain and use a substitute as well. (`\bfseries` is only interested in whether you are in math mode or not.)

The command `\textbf` uses LaTeX's new font selection scheme, i.e., it tries to be clever in "adding boldness" to the font family and font shape that is used at the position where it is called. By default, it tries to add extended bold because that's what you would expect when using the default family Computer Modern (or Latin Modern).

The document class `article` also only loads some specific font sizes and complains if you try to use something extraordinary.

2) Yes. Well, it depends. First, try using `\package{lmodern}`and see, if that better fits your needs. It allows for more font sizes and doesn't complain about that. If you are using pdf(la)tex, take a look here: [Suppress fontaxes warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127063/suppress-fontaxes-warnings)

* Don't bet your money on this.

Comment: \bfseries gives the same message if it used *before* \textbf. The first one wins.

Comment: Well, it doesn't on my system, which is TeXLive, using pdftex. However, as I said in my answer, if you use `lmodern`, there should be no errors at all.

Comment: The thing is that I want `newpx` :-) So being consistent with using `bfseries`, would only invoke one _LaTeX Font Info_ and "maybe" increase the speed.

Comment: This are not errors but substituation messages (in this case harmless). And switching to a completly different font is not really a solution.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is not an error, just a message. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that the font was important to you. Since I'm on TeXLive, I can't reproduce your error. But you could try the following command: `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}`. That should make `bfseries` choose bold instead of bold extended.