# Suppressing badbox messages does not work

Tags: warnings, badness

For me thesis, I want to suppress all badbox message until it is somewhat finished to concentrate on the more pressing warnings. As suggest here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164889/81936 I tried using the silence package. This did not change anything. I guess because badbox is actually neither a warning nor an error.

As suggested here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50850/81936, I added

```
\hfuzz=10000pt
\vfuzz=10000pt
\hbadness=2000
\vbadness=\maxdimen
```

to my header.
This also had no effect. The structure of my thesis looks like this

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}
\input{chapters/header}
\input{chapters/symbols}
%%BODY
\begin{document}
\include{chapters/preamble}
\mainmatter
%many chapters that throw badbox messages
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\include{chapters/appendix}
\end{document}
```

I set the \hfuzz stuff in the header.tex file.

Comment: what messages do you get? (you could set hbadness=10000 to silence more)

Comment: I have set hbadness=10000. I stil get bad box message. E.g. `Overfull \hbox (16.9164pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
\OT1/cmr/m/sl/10 CHAPTER 5.  ADVANTAGES OF GAUSSIAN PROCESS PANEL MODELING \OT1
/cmr/m/n/10 35
 []`
 and `Overfull \hbox (200.03493pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 647--648
[][] 
 []`

Comment: overfull box warnings are do not report "badness" so are not affected by that, you could set \hfuzz to some value > 17pt to silence that message, if you have set it as you show but still see the message something is setting it back. Hard to say without a real example to reproduce.

Comment: most likely you (or a package you are using) have used `\sloppy` or `\fussy` both of which set `\hfuzz` to less than 16.9pt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is also what I suspected. Therefore, I placed \hfuzz=10000pt after all packages have been loaded. Apparently,  this does not solve the problem. Is there a way to declare hfuzz as a constant, such that changing its value will either be permitted or throws an error?

Comment: placing it after the package won't help if your headline code uses `\sloppy` as it will reset it within the headline so... `\hfuzz=\maxdimen\newdimen\hfuzz`  if you _really_ must? (this sets then hides the real `\hfuzz` making `\hfuzz` point to an otherwise unused register than has no affect on the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While reducing some warnings while drafting is probably good, silencing badness 10000 (infinitely bad) or overfull 200pt (probably off the page) boxes seems like it is taking that idea to extremes but if you want to do that set

```
\hbadness=10000
\hfuzz=\maxdimen
```

to set the primitives to their maximum effective values, then do

```
\newcount\hbadness
\newdimen\hfuzz
```

to replace those commands by registers so that any later settings by other package code will have no effect.