# How to remove (or at least suppress) "fontmap entry for <font> already exists" warnings

Tags: fonts, warnings, logging

## Background

I cannot seem to find a solution that works and sufficiently explains what I need to do.

I do not use Latex much, so please explain as if I don't know how Latex works, because that's mostly true.

When I build a Latex file (using TeXStudio to generate PDFs, but I've also used other Tex IDEs), a **gigantic** log file is always created. The logfile itself is > 5 MB!!

The reason for this is a myriad of warnings captured in the log file like this (I have a Mac, if it matters):

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): fontmap entry for `ts1-zi4nr' already exists, duplicates ignored
```

Duplicates are ignored, the document compiles, but these warnings are so tiresome and tedious.

## Attempts to Date

So, I looked into `updmap` and ran

```
updmap-user --listmaps
```

There are many maps (approx. 200), but they are all located in one file:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

So I cannot delete that file, obviously, since it contains all the fonts.

---

After first trying to find an easy way to suppress all errors, and ineffectively [using `\hbadness=10000` to suppress them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66959/168706), I've just tried to ignore these senseless errors for months. But it slows down **any** progress I need to do any time I need to go back and touch Latex.

Please help, as I'm about to give up on Latex and go back to RevealJS, which cannot really do the job as well as Latex, for my purposes.

Comment: does updmap-sys regenerate the pdftex.map above? If yes, check which cfg-file it loads.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm sorry, I just don't know enough about Latex to say. This is why I was asking to please be detailed and clear with instructions. Thanks!

Comment: I have no mac, I'm on Windows.  I can't  give you clear instructions. Run updmap-says in a terminal and look what it says.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't have `updmap-says` available, only `updmap`, `updmap-sys`, and `updmap-user`. The help is a few pages long. The options to `updmap` that seemed most logical to try were `--listmaps` and `--listavailablemaps`. Other the others seem to be flags to set things, like `--enable <MAPTYPE>`. This is why I'm stuck: I can't make heads or tails of the Latex documentation. :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh come on. Use your brain. Which of the three variants could I have meant if you take possible typos into account? Run it without option to see what it does, which files it reads and which it writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how helpful this will be to other users, but the problem was that *everything* that LaTeX installed had the wrong file permissions.

I needed to go to all of the files installed under `/usr/local/texlive/2018` (which was the default location for my Mac OS install) and change them all to be *writeable*.

It had nothing to do with duplicate files, despite the error that claimed as such.

---

If anyone else runs into a similar error, be sure to check `updmap-sys`, or really any `updmap` command, since they will all point you to where your fonts actually live. Then go ahead and fix all of their permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I hit a similar error message on Fedora Linux. Turns out that this time it was due to a bug in the Fedora version of the Texlive package. I managed to solve it be  by re-installing the offending package, as described in this link: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2020188