# Eliminate overfull hbox warning for mdframed frame that goes into margin

Tags: spacing, mdframed

I like my `mdframed` frames to go into the margin, so that the text is not effected, by using a negative `leftmargin` and `rightmargin`.  However this results in an

> Overfull \hbox (0.43031pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--16

I don't want to eliminate *all* overfull box warnings as I still want to know if there are issues with the text.

So, how do I eliminate this warning just for the frame, but not for the text?

### References:

- [What does "overfull hbox" mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean)
- [How to suppress overfull hbox warnings up to some maximum?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13715/how-to-suppress-overfull-hbox-warnings-up-to-some-maximum)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{MyStyle}{%
    leftmargin=-5pt,
    rightmargin=-5pt,
    backgroundcolor=yellow!25,
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyStyle]
    \noindent\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This particular `Overfull \hbox` message is due to a bad paragraph. Try with `\usepackage[latin]{babel}` and it will disappear.

Comment: If you add `draft` as a class option, you will see that the line ending on `magna.` is the culprit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overfull `\hbox` warnings are dependent on the length `\hfuzz`. Setting this to something long removes them from the output warnings. Consider, for example,

```
\newcommand{\ignoreoverfullhboxes}{\setlength{\hfuzz}{\maxdimen}}
```

(or something smaller than `\maxdimen`; default for `\hfuzz` is `0.1pt`). Issue `\ignoreoverfullhboxes` wherever needed (and localize its scope within an environment).

Using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), you can call `\ignoreoverfullhboxes` at the start of every `mdframed` environment using

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{mdframed}{\ignoreoverfullhboxes}
```