# Overfull hbox with fleqn and autonum

Tags: amsmath, autonum

I am using `autonum` and `amsmath` with the `fleqn` option to left-align equations.  However, this combination appears to generate `Overfull \hbox` warnings at the `\begin{document}` line.  I am using the latest Macports TeXLive distribution.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}

Some filler text.

\end{document}
```

And here's what the pdflatex build log shows:

```
Overfull \hbox (5.00003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--6
 [] 
 []


Overfull \hbox (5.00003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--6
 [] 
 []


Overfull \hbox (15.00003pt too wide) detected at line 6
 []$[]     $ 
 []


Overfull \hbox (5.00003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--6
 [] 
 []


Overfull \hbox (5.00003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--6
 [] 
 []
```

I don't actually see any typesetting problems, so it seems like the warnings are just cluttering the log.  The warnings disappear if I remove the `fleqn` option.

Is there some unseen problem with using the `autonum` package with left-aligned equations?  How can I fix or hide these warnings and still maintain the `fleqn` behavior?

Comment: You can suppress warnings up to a certain point  if that is tolerable.  `\hfuzz = 16pt`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13715/how-to-suppress-overfull-hbox-warnings-up-to-some-maximum

Comment: @dustin: seems like a reasonable option.  Although, since I'd rather not set `\hfuzz` to something that large globally, I guess I could patch `autonum` in the right place.

Comment: @dustin No, that's wrong advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem due to the timing when the relevant parameters are set. However it can be fixed by telling `autonum` to ignore overfull box messages when it does its tentative math environment in order to establish some internal values.

The code

```
\def\autonum@saveEnvironmentSubcommands#1#2#3{%
\begin{textblock}{1}[1,1](0,0)%
\begin{#2}%
```

(lines 107–109 in `autonum.sty`) should better be

```
\def\autonum@saveEnvironmentSubcommands#1#2#3{%
\begin{textblock}{1}[1,1](0,0)%
\hfuzz=\maxdimen % ignore overfull box messages
\begin{#2}%
```

and you can patch it until it's fixed in the package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{autonum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\autonum@saveEnvironmentSubcommands}
  {(0,0)\begin}
  {(0,0)\hfuzz=\maxdimen\begin}                              
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some filler text.
\begin{equation}\label{a}
1=1
\end{equation}
%\ref{a}

\end{document}
```

This setting of `\hfuzz` will be local to the `textblock` environment, so it won't affect the rest of the document.