# Disable (only for some part of the document) some warnings

Tags: macros, warnings, dimensions, logging

Is it possible to create two commands `\disableOverfullWarnings` and `\enableOverfullWarnings` that respectively disable and enable the printing of messages such as

> Overfull \hbox (12.92616pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 157--158 ...

in the console (in the output of `pdftex`)?

Thanks

PS: If not possible, is it possible to disable *all* warnings for some part of the document?

---

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of 
[How to suppress overfull hbox warnings up to some maximum?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13715/how-to-suppress-overfull-hbox-warnings-up-to-some-maximum).

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate!

Comment: in what way is it not a duplicate? (I could re-open but I couldn't give any other answer than the one there)

Comment: `\disableOverfullWarnings` is `\hfuzz=\maxdimen` and that will turn off at the end of the current environment or if you do `\hfuzz=0.1pt`

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean now. I thought one could disable a warning without any consideration on dimensions. But your idea is fine! Thanks! If you wish to make it an answer (I still think it is not a duplicate).