# Silencing overfull hbox warning for listing in adjustbox

Tags: listings, warnings, size, adjustbox

I have the following in my document and it works as I expect, scaling the listing to fit the page, but it gives me a spurious `Overfull \hbox` warning that I would like to get rid of:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
A long line of code which I want to be scaled to fit the page.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}
```

Here is the warning:

```
Overfull \hbox (27.00378pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--9
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] 
 []
```

where line 8 is the long line inside the listing.

Is there a clean way to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13716/121799)? (I did not test it.)

Comment: @marmot I don't want to remove overfull warnings for the rest of the document though. Can I put `hfuzz` in a group?

Comment: I don't know, can't you just try out (e.g. by doing the listing twice, once in a group with this and once without)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Overfull \hbox` warning is from the `lstlisting` environment which creates a paragraph box `\linewidth` long and the content is wider than that. Scaling it down afterwards makes it fit then, but does not remove the previous warning.

One easy way to avoid this is to make the listings paragraph wider, which can be done by wrapping it into a `varwidth` environment with a wide enough width. `adjustbox` can do this for you be adding the `varwidth=<width>` key. Here you can take `\maxdimen` to ensure that is as wide as possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{varwidth=\maxdimen,max width=\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
A long line of code which I want to be scaled to fit the page.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The process of inserting `hfuzz=<dimen>` specifically when using the [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) environment can be automated using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,adjustbox,etoolbox,lipsum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{adjustbox}{\hfuzz=100pt}% Choose your poison

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
A long line of code which I want to be scaled to fit the page.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by marmot, using `\hfuzz` to remove the warning works. I don't think this solution is elegant, though. It seem to me like an error that the listing inside the adjustbox gives the warning to begin with.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.5\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
A long line of code which I want to be scaled to fit the page.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}

% No warning:
{\hfuzz=10000pt
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.5\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
A long line of code which I want to be scaled to fit the page.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}
}

% Warning:
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.5\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
A long line of code which I want to be scaled to fit the page.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```