# Table row centering causing entire table to break

Tags: tables

Below is the table that I am trying to diagnose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}  >{\centering} m{1.67cm}| >{\centering} m{0.7cm} 
                       >{\centering} m{0.7cm} >{\centering} m{0.7cm} >{\centering} m{0.7cm} 
                       >{\centering} m{0.7cm} >{\centering} m{0.7cm} >{\centering} m{0.7cm}                 
                       >{\centering} m{0.7cm} @{}}
       Test & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ \newline $8$ \newline $9$ & $8$ \\
       \hline
       \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      \hline
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 \\
      \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

If I try to compile this, it gives several `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr` errors and the entire table is a mess. However, if I just remove the final `>{\centering}` from the last column, everything looks fine. How can I include the centering and have the table show up fine?  The `@{}` included in the tabular brackets came from a suggestion in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/overfull-hbox-warning-when-using-tabular), which didn't end up solving the problem.

As an additional side-question, if I change the document class from `article` to `revtex4-1`, the rows with entries that have newlines (the first row) is no longer vertically centered. Does anyone know what's up with that, and how to get vertical centering in tables with revtex?

Comment: What are these `\newline` commands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some suggestions. In the captions to the table, I have explained the changes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{corrected the use of centering by adding arraybackslash, simplified column declaration}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}  >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.67cm}| *{8}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{0.7cm}}@{}}
       Test & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ \newline $8$ \newline $9$ & $8$ \\
       \hline
       \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      \hline
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 \\
      \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{Used makecell from the makecell package in order to get the linebreaks in column 8}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}  >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{1.67cm}| *{8}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} p{0.7cm}}@{}}
       Test & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & \makecell{$7$ \\ $8$ \\ $9$} & $8$ \\
       \hline
       \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      \hline
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 \\
      \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{Since no automatic linebreaks in table cells seem to be needed, why not just go for simple c type columns?}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}  c| *{8}{c}@{}}
       Test & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & \makecell{$7$ \\ $8$ \\ $9$} & $8$ \\
       \hline
       \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      \hline
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 \\
      \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{If you prefer wider cells but do not need automatic linebreaks, why not go for the new column type W from the array package?}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}  Wc{1.67cm}| *{8}{Wc{0.7cm}}@{}}
       Test & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & \makecell{$7$ \\ $8$ \\ $9$} & $8$ \\
       \hline
       \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      \hline
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 \\
      \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant that use `tabular*`, `\extracolsep{fill}` and nested tabular to create the multiline cell in the heading. [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) is a simple way to adjust the width of the caption to match the width of the table

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, threeparttable}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\begin {document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \caption{A caption with lot of interesting information of how to interpret the complicated figures and mathematics in the tabular}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.8\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}c| *{8}{c}@{}}
            Test & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                                                       $7$ \\ $8$ \\ $9$\end{tabular} & $8$ \\
           \hline
           \hline
           1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
           \hline
           1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 \\
           \hline
           1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
           \hline
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```