# Getting table to fit

Tags: tables

I am trying to get a large table to fit the page. I have tried multiple solutions found on this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/overfull-hbox-warning-when-using-tabular). I am not sure if I am understanding the issue correctly. The error is overfull \hbox. Here is the table I am trying to set up. I have tried removing a couple of the columns and it was fine, but I would prefer keeping everything.

```
\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm} % modify this if you need even more space
\begin{landscape}
\subsubsection{co variance Matrix}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
    \tiny

    \caption{Co variance Matrix}
    \label{tab:cmcDataCoVar}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4m}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}|p{.4cm}}
    \hline
     1.0&-0.1&-0.2& 0.0&-0.2& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1&-0.1\\
    -0.1& 1.0&-0.1&-0.3& 0.1&-0.3& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
    -0.2&-0.1& 1.0& 0.5& 0.4& 0.3& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1& 0.1\\
    -0.0&-0.3& 0.5& 1.0& 0.4& 0.8&-0.1& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1& 0.0\\
    -0.2& 0.1& 0.4& 0.4& 1.0&-0.2&-0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1& 0.0\\
     0.1&-0.3& 0.3& 0.8&-0.2& 1.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0&-0.1&-0.1& 0.0& 0.3& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.1& 0.0&-0.1&-0.1&-0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.2&-0.2\\
    -0.1& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1& 0.0&-0.2& 0.2\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: I get an error `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` as you have `.4m` not `.4cm` but other than that if I guess the parts you didn't show as `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}` then it fits easily on the page  [the output is this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7d9y.png)

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn I checked that they were all correct multiple times, but I am new to it so I thought the error was coming from something I didnt understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already pointed out in a comment, there's a typo in one of the `p`-type columns: `p{.4m}`.  As `m` is not a valid length unit for TeX, TeX generates an error message. Replacing `p{.4m}` with `p{.4cm}` is the obvious remedy.

For the table at hand, it makes sense to want all 26 columns to have equal width. However, it makes little sense to use the `p` column type, as surely you'll *never* want line breaking to occur in any of the cells. I suggest you switch to the `w` column type; it lets you specify a fixed usable width, but it won't allow automatic line breaking. Moreover, don't just assign an arbitrary width (of 4mm, say); instead, just *measure* the needed width via a `\settowidth` instruction. See the code below for how to implement this idea.

I would further like to suggest that you (a) employ an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment (since the contents of all columns are "math-y"), (b) reduce the amount of inter-column whitespace padding (specifically, from 5pt to 3pt), and (c) right-align the cells in order to make the numbers look like they're aligned on the decimal markers.

With these changes in place, there happily is no need to run `\tiny`; indeed, `\small` will do just fine. Your readers will definitely appreciate that you're not forcing them to squint -- or go looking for a magnifying glass.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{geometry,pdflscape}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth{\mylen}{\small$-0.2$} % measure the required (usable) width of columns

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm} % modify this as needed

\begin{landscape}
\subsubsection*{Covariance matrix}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}    % default: 5pt
    \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt} % for a less cramped "look"
    \small % not \tiny

    \caption{Covariance matrix}
    \label{tab:cmcDataCoVar}
    
    \medskip
    $\begin{array}{| *{26}{wr{\mylen}|} }
    \hline
     1.0&-0.1&-0.2& 0.0&-0.2& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1&-0.1\\
    -0.1& 1.0&-0.1&-0.3& 0.1&-0.3& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
    -0.2&-0.1& 1.0& 0.5& 0.4& 0.3& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1& 0.1\\
    -0.0&-0.3& 0.5& 1.0& 0.4& 0.8&-0.1& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1& 0.0\\
    -0.2& 0.1& 0.4& 0.4& 1.0&-0.2&-0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1& 0.0\\
     0.1&-0.3& 0.3& 0.8&-0.2& 1.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0&-0.1&-0.1& 0.0& 0.3& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0&-0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1\\
     0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0\\
     0.1& 0.0&-0.1&-0.1&-0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.2&-0.2\\
    -0.1& 0.0& 0.1& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0& 0.0&-0.1& 0.0&-0.2& 0.2\\
    \hline
    \end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be added that `m` is not a valid unit in TeX and therefore the error `Illegal unit of measure` comes up.

Comment: @JasperHabicht - Thanks. I've rewritten the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, I had checked but must have missed it multiple times. I am new so thought the error was from something else like the margins.

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov the error message in log does show the exact point at which the error occurs.