# Forbid hyphenations for a particular text

Tags: hyphenation

How can I temporarily forbid hyphenations (or make them more "expensive"), for a particular piece of text? One or two paragraphs.

Comment: Will \hyphenpenalty=10000 work?  That is as high a penalty as you can assign.  (The normal value is much lower, something like 50.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the discussion in [How to reduce the number of hyphenation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31301/5764), you could define an environment that sets some hyphenation-avoiding parameters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newenvironment{nohyphen}
  {\tolerance=1% Also consider setting \pretolerance
   \emergencystretch=\maxdimen%
   \hyphenpenalty=10000%
   \hbadness=10000}% \begin{nohyphen}
  {\par}% \end{nohyphen}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{nohyphen}
\lipsum[1]
\end{nohyphen}
\end{document}
```

The parameter selection was taken from [Justify without hyphenation](http://sumanta679.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/latex-justify-without-hyphenation/) and, as suggested in the first post, may require some tweaking. More on this, including a discussion regarding the above parameters, is available from the TeX FAQ entry [Stopping all hyphenation](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff).

With regards to line-breaking and some of the considerations on TeX's side, also review [(La)TeX makes overfull lines](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-overfull):

> TeX’s first attempt at breaking lines is performed without even trying
> hyphenation: TeX sets its “tolerance” of line breaking oddities to the
> internal value `\pretolerance`, and sees what happens. If it can’t get
> an acceptable break, TeX adds the hyphenation points allowed by the
> current patterns, and tries again using the internal `\tolerance`
> value. If this pass also fails, and the internal `\emergencystretch`
> value is positive, TeX will try a pass that allows `\emergencystretch`
> worth of extra stretchability to the spaces in each line.
>
> In principle, therefore, there are three parameters (other than
> hyphenation) that you can change: `\pretolerance`, `\tolerance` and
> `\emergencystretch`.

Answer (score 3):

1. For a short text (a word) use `\mbox{content}`.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}\noindent
   \begin{minipage}{2cm}
       content content\\content \mbox{content}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. For one word through the entire document use `\hyphenation{content}` in the preamble.
3. For a paragraph or more use `\raggedright` (this will drop justification, though).
4. For an integer amount of paragraphs you can set penalties:

   ```
   \tolerance=1
   \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
   \hyphenpenalty=10000
   \hbadness=10000
   ```

Comment: I'd like it with a bit longer text (one or two paragraphs). Can you suggest a way, without dropping the justification?

Comment: @MayGodBlessKnuth I've updated my answer but [Werner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74293/16595) was a little bit faster. I recommend to use an environment like he did so that you don't forget the `\par` or the blank line.

Comment: I don't understand; How come setting `\rightskip` to `0pt plus 1fil` removes hyphenation? TeXbook says “this isn’t a particularly good way to make ragged-right margins, because the infinite stretchability will assign zero badness to lines that are very short.”

Comment: @morbusg There's no penalty for using infinite stretch (`plus 1fil`), but there's a penalty for hyphenating a word. That's why the line-breaking algorithm will choose not to hyphenate. Some people (e.g. David Carlisle I think) prefer to put `\rightskip 0pt plus 7em` (or any other finite value at your wish), which leads to most words not being hyphenated, but when the line would be too short, they get hyphenated.