# How to wrap a word in line without hyphen?

Tags: line-breaking

I m writing one article in which i need to write a paragraph full of medical terms. How can i wrap a text in a line without using line break (or hyphen)?

Regards

Comment: To prevent a word from breaking you may put it in a `\mbox{....}`. To avoid hyphens you may also use `\usepackage{hyphenat}` and use `\nohyphens{<text>}`. To make it global use `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`

Comment: Another technique is to typeset the paragraph in question in `\raggedright` mode. This may be preferable to maintaining full justification. The latter is likely to produce some lines with huge inter-word gaps when hyphenation is turned off.

Comment: This may or may not be what the OP is asking, but one question is how to line-break a word without the hyphen character, i.e. hyphenation without a hyphen. If this is *not* what the OP means, it might be useful to change the title from "wrap a word" to something like "wrap text" to prevent a misreading.

Comment: [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31301/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-hyphenation)?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: [Wrapping long lines that contain no spaces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6171).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can break a word with no hyphen at the end of the line (see the other answers), but then it doesn't look like a broken word. It might be a good idea to use some other symbol there instead of the hyphen, for instance `$\bm\cdot$` (with `\usepackage{bm}`). This can be done by defining:

```
\newcommand{\+}{\discretionary{\mbox{${\bm\cdot}\mkern-1mu$}}{}{}}
```

I strongly recommend using the package `microtype` too, which helps a lot here. I added a small negative `\mkern` after the dot, to make it protrude a bit to the right margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\+}{\discretionary{\mbox{${\bm\cdot}\mkern-1mu$}}{}{}}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\hsize 4.75cm

x\hfill x

This is my\-very\-long\-word\-that\-I\-want\-to\-break\-at\-any\-of\-these\-given\-points

This is my\+very\+long\+word\+that\+I\+want\+to\+break\+at\+any\+of\+these\+given\+points

\renewcommand\+{\discretionary{}{}{}}

This is my\+very\+long\+word\+that\+I\+want\+to\+break\+at\+any\+of\+these\+given\+points

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to add spaces within text instead of using hyphen for line breaking.

Comment: @user15662 Sorry, but I got completely lost and I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to split a word but don't want a hyphen to be used where the split happens, you can define a new hyphenation style:

```
\def\+{\discretionary{}{}{}}
```

Now you can use it as in `a\+very\+long\+word`. However, this still requires to place this new non-hyphen manually.

From the TeXBook:

> A discretionary break consists of three sequences of characters called
>   the pre- break, post-break, and no-break texts. The idea is that if a
>   line break occurs here, the pre-break text will appear at the end of
>   the current line and the post-break text will occur at the beginning
>   of the next line; but if no break occurs, the no-break text will
>   appear in the current line. Users can specify discretionary breaks in
>   complete generality by writing
>
> `\discretionary{⟨pre-break text⟩}{⟨post-break text⟩}{⟨no-break text⟩}`
>
> where the three texts consist entirely of characters, boxes, and
>   kerns. For example, TEX can hyphenate the word ‘difficult’ between the
>   f’s, even though this requires breaking the ‘ffi’ ligature into ‘f-’
>   followed by an ‘fi’ ligature, if the horizontal list contains
>   `di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{ffi}cult`.

Comment: When using the `babel` package, the same effect (text breaking without hyphen) is accomplished with the notation `""`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
\usepackage{seqsplit}
```

and then use

```
\seqsplit{ATGTCCACTGATAAAAGTACACGCTATAATTTTCAGATTGAGAAAGCCCC
CTCGTTGGCGTACGCTGCAGGTCGAC}
```

this can be used for displaying DNA sequences, but probably does an alright job in your case as well