# Is there any macro to break a long word that is longer than linewidth and not in dictionary?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, columnbreak

Actually here I have a long set which is flanked by `\left\{` and `\right\}`, and it is longer than the line width but LaTeX cannot break it into two lines. I want to keep the set in the same way (because I have a lot sets which are too long and already stored) but use a new environment or command to break it into lines. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. A [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would help us help you, and provide a solution to your problem. Off the top of my head I'd suggest using `\bigl` and `\bigr` with `\allowbreak` or the `breqn`package, as `\left` and `\right` produce an unbreakable block

Comment: you should edit the question to match the title, or edit the title to match the question as they are completely separate issues. `\left` `\right` is an unbreakable box and there is no hyphenation in math mode, so the question of breaking that is completely separate from breaking words with not enough hyphenation points in text

Comment: here are two previous questions that may be helpful: [How to break long words after n chars (long genomic sequences)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116441) and [How to wrap a word in line without hyphen?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100391)