# Wrap long text content that have no spaces

Tags: pdftex

I have been struggling to find a way to wrap text content in LaTeX.

For example, if I have a piece of text which is something like

```
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

Of course, this is not something you would normally do in a document but in some cases like long URLs the content can be long like this. Yes, you could use \url etc.. but I want it as plain text with no other markup applied to the content.

So when there is no spacing between the start of the text and the end of the margin then the text just continues where I would expect the content to wrap onto a new line when reaching the margin.

Is there a way I can get LaTeX to wrap the text and handle this sort of problem?

Comment: Are all characters in the string the same, without distinct syllabae like in [Llanfairpwllgwyngyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyll)/Llanfair­pwllgwyngyll­gogery­chwyrn­drobwll­llan­tysilio­gogo­goch to add a manual hyphenation pattern?  (Note the post stamp with the text as a spiral.)  For context, is the string about a gene sequence?  (The hyphenation applied here was introduced by tex.se ...)

Comment: This might be helpful: [How to wrap a word in line without hyphen?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100391)

Comment: See the `seqsplit` package, which defines an eponymous command.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can define `\enablehyph` macro:

```
\def\enablehyph#1{\enablehyphA #1\end}
\def\enablehyphA#1{\ifx\end#1\unskip\unpenalty
   \else#1\penalty0\hskip0pt plus1pt\relax
   \expandafter\enablehyphA\fi}

\enablehyph{dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}
```

This macro inserts `\penalty0 \hskip0pt plus1pt` between each letter of the word. It means that the kerning between letters is lost.

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, is there away to apply this across all the content without having to include it each time?

Comment: @DanMaia I am going to take a stab and say the short answer is "no".  The problem would be on not knowing whether a sequence of characters is plain text for which to apply `\penalty0` or some argument to a command, for example `15pt`, in which the application of extra interleaved tokens would break the code.

Comment: @DanMaia What do you mean with “all the content”? Do you really want that any word, short or long, is split at random places?